# Converter data dd/mm/aaaa para yyyy-mm-dd'T'HH:mm:ss

Tags: java, android, data, simpledateformat

Como eu faço para converter uma data no formato `dd/mm/yyyy` para o formato suportado pelo SQLite `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss`?

Exemplo:

```
public static String converteStringEmData(String stringData) throws ParseException { 
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/mm/aaaa");//yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss
    SimpleDateFormat output = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
    Date data = sdf.parse(stringData);
    String formattedTime = output.format(data);
    return formattedTime;
}
```

Comment: Está retornando algum erro se sim qual erro ?!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Douglas,

Já tive um problema parecido ao converter datas, veja se o exemplo abaixo ajuda a direcionar o seu problema.

```
  try {
      Log.e(MainActivity.class.getSimpleName(), converteStringEmData("21/03/2014"));
   } catch (ParseException ex) {
      ex.printStackTrace();
   }


public static String converteStringEmData(String stringData) throws ParseException  { 
   SimpleDateFormat simpleDateForma2 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy", Locale.getDefault());
   Date receivedDate = simpleDateForma2.parse(stringData);

   String formatedDate = DateFormat.format("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss", receivedDate).toString();
   return formatedDate;
}
```

Abs!

Comment: É isso aí :D funcionou direitinho.

Comment: @DouglasMesquita se o problema está resolvido marque o V do lado da resposta que te ajudou para indicar que ela é a correta.

Comment: Ah, legal. Não sabia disso :P

Answer (score 2):

A partir da API Level 26 (necessário *minSdkVersion* >= 26, não basta ter *compileSdkVersion* >= 26), é possível usar as classes do [pacote `java.time`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/time/package-summary).

Uma diferença fundamental é que esta API possui [várias classes diferentes para representar datas e horas](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/iso/overview.html) (como por exemplo, uma classe para representar somente dia, mês e ano, outra para representar datas com horário, ou com fuso horário, etc). Isso é bem diferente de [`java.util.Date`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Date.html), que sempre representa um ponto na linha do tempo (ou seja, o `Date` na verdade corresponde a um timestamp).

E quando você faz um *parsing* de uma `String` que não contém o horário, [`SimpleDateFormat`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) automaticamente seta o horário para meia-noite no timezone *default* da JVM. Por isso ao converter "dd/MM/yyyy" para o formato "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", os campos relativos ao horário (hora, minuto e segundo) serão zero.

Porém, o `java.time` não faz estas "mágicas" automaticamente (segundo o criador da API, [por uma decisão de *design*](https://sourceforge.net/p/threeten/mailman/message/32911367/)), e você deve setar explicitamente o horário desejado:

```java
// criar a data a partir da string
String s = "21/03/2014";
DateTimeFormatter parser = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/uuuu");
LocalDate data = LocalDate.parse(s, parser);

// setar o horário para meia-noite e converter para outro formato
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
String dataFormatada = formatter.format(data.atTime(LocalTime.MIDNIGHT));
System.out.println(dataFormatada); // 2014-03-21 00:00:00
```

Primeiro eu converti a `String` no formato "dia/mês/ano" para um [`java.time.LocalDate`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/time/LocalDate.html) (uma classe que só possui dia, mês e ano).

Em seguida eu seto o horário para meia-noite (usando o método [`atTime`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/time/LocalDate.html#atTime(java.time.LocalTime))) e converto o resultado para o formato desejado. O resultado é `2014-03-21 00:00:00`.

---

No título da pergunta é citado o formato "yyyy-mm-dd'T'HH:mm:ss" (com a letra `T` em vez de um espaço) - [este formato é definido pela norma ISO 8601](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/406210/112052), e a classe [`java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter) possui algumas constantes pre-definidas para formatos compatíveis com a ISO 8601:

```java
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE_TIME;
String dataFormatada = formatter.format(data.atTime(LocalTime.MIDNIGHT));
```

Agora a `String` resultante é `2014-03-21T00:00:00`.

Apenas um detalhe: caso o horário tenha frações de segundo, [`DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE_TIME`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter#ISO_DATE_TIME) faz com que estas sejam mostradas. Já se eu usar um formato fixo, como por exemplo `DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss")`, aí as frações de segundo não serão mostradas, independente do seu valor (repare que a letra `T` está entre aspas simples, para que seja interpretada como um texto literal, caso contrário será lançada uma exceção).

Outro detalhe é que para as horas eu usei `HH` (maiúsculo), que mostra a hora com valores entre 00 e 23. Na outra resposta foi usado `hh` (minúsculo), que mostra os valores entre 00 e 12 (ou seja, é um valor ambíguo, que pode ser desambiguado se você usar os designadores AM e PM - bastando adicionar a letra `a` no *pattern* passado para `DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern`).

Note também que no primeiro exemplo usei `u` em vez de `y` para o ano, pois o `y` não funciona para datas AC (Antes de Cristo). Como `u` funciona para ambos os casos (AC e DC), acaba sendo a melhor escolha (e este campo é o mesmo usado por `DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE_TIME`, a propósito). Veja [esta resposta do SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41178418/540552) para entender melhor os detalhes.

---

#### API Level < 26

Caso você não possa usar o `java.time`, uma alternativa é o [ThreeTen Backport](https://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/), um excelente *backport* do `java.time`. A maioria das funcionalidades está presente, com algumas diferenças: em vez das classes estarem no pacote `java.time`, elas ficam no pacote `org.threeten.bp`. [Veja aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754) como configurá-lo para Android.