# Formato das datas numa NF-e

Tags: php, javascript, data, nfe

Estou desenvolvendo de uma tela que irá gerar uma NF-e e no momento que fui trabalhar com as datas descobri que precisam ser enviadas num formato específico que não conheço e nem achei nada na internet. O formato é esse:

```
2015-02-12T15:20:16-02:00
```

Alguém saberia me explicar que formato seria esse? E como o montá-lo, pois preciso trabalhar com ele.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Esse formato é o padrão UTC (UTC - Universal Coordinated Time), onde a data é formada por `"AAAA-MM-DDThh:mm:ssTZD"`.

Onde:

- **AAAA**: Ano
- **MM**: Mês
- **DD**: Dia
- **hh**: Horas
- **mm**: Minutos
- **ss**: Segundos
- **TZD**: Seu timezone (fuso-horário)

Quanto ao formato, tu podes encontrar o que precisas [nesse link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2487921/convert-date-format-yyyy-mm-dd-dd-mm-yyyy) do próprio SO.

Comment: O T ali no meio é um separador apenas?

Comment: Sim, o **T** é fixo.

Comment: Obrigado amigo, me ajudou muito.

Answer (score 3):

Este formato é definido pela [norma ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601). Basicamente, ela define a ordem dos campos (sempre "ano-mês-dia-hora-minuto-segundo-*offset*"), além dos seus valores e tamanhos:

- ano com no mínimo 4 dígitos (ou seja, o ano 1 deve ser escrito como `0001`)
- mês, dia, hora, minuto e segundo sempre com 2 dígitos, e completados com um zero à esquerda caso seja menor que 10 (ou seja, fevereiro deve ser `02` em vez de apenas `2`)
- mês entre `01` e `12`
- dia entre `01` e `31`
- hora entre `00` e `24` (embora o valor `24` signifique "o final do dia", que é o mesmo que meia-noite do dia seguinte - ou seja, `2019-08-05T24:00` é o mesmo que `2019-08-06T00:00`)
- minuto entre `00` e `59`
- segundo entre `00` e `60` (sendo que o valor `60` é usado para indicar um [*leap second*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leap_second))

  - também são permitidas frações de segundo (na verdade, as horas e minutos também permitem frações, desde que este seja o último elemento presente, ou seja, `14:30.5` e `14:30:30` seriam equivalentes, mas `14:30.5:01` seria inválido)

Entre a data e a hora, sempre é colocada a letra "**T**" maiúscula, embora seja permitido a substituição desta por um espaço, **desde que** haja um "acordo mútuo" entre as partes que manipularão a data (existem também outros padrões, como a [RFC 3339](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3339), que permite um espaço no lugar do `T`, [entre outras diferenças](https://stackoverflow.com/a/522281)).

A norma ISO 8601 também define os separadores (hífens entre ano, mês e dia; dois-pontos entre hora, minuto e segundo), embora também admita um formato básico sem separadores. Ou seja, tanto `2015-02-12T15:20:16-02:00` quanto `20150212T152016-0200` seriam válidos* (o último hífen antes do `02` não é um separador, e sim o sinal de negativo, conforme veremos mais abaixo).

***** *Quando eu digo que ambos os formatos são válidos, estou me referindo às definições da norma ISO 8601. Isso não quer dizer necessariamente que sua aplicação vai aceitar ambos (sempre consulte a respectiva documentação).*

---

Por fim, a norma também define o [*Time zone designator*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Time_zone_designators), que apesar do nome, não é de fato um *timezone*.

*Timezones* são um conjunto de regras que definem o horário local de uma determinada região, incluindo as mudanças que este sofre ao longo do tempo. O mais comum e usado são os [*timezones* do TZDB da IANA](https://www.iana.org/time-zones), que definem identificadores como `America/Sao_Paulo` e `Europe/London`. Cada identificador possui o histórico de alterações que o horário local de sua respectiva região sofreu ao longo do tempo. O *timezone* `America/Sao_Paulo`, por exemplo, possui todas as mudanças de horário de verão correspondentes ao Horário de Brasília (ou seja, o histórico de todas as datas e horas exatas em que o relógio foi adiantado ou atrasado em uma hora).

<sup>*O nome do timezone não é `America/Brasilia` porque [o critério da IANA é usar o nome da maior cidade de cada região](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/259124/112052)*</sup>

Enfim, o que a norma ISO 8601 usa em seu formato é na verdade um [*offset*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC_offset), que basicamente é a diferença com relação a [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time). Por exemplo, o *timezone* `America/Sao_Paulo` está, na maior parte do ano, 3 horas atrás do UTC, que é representado pelo *offset* `-03:00`. Mas durante o horário de verão, os relógios são adiantados em uma hora e ele passa a estar 2 horas atrás de UTC (ou seja, o *offset* muda para `-02:00`).

<sup>*Em 2019 o Brasil não terá horário de verão, mas o timezone `America/Sao_Paulo` mantém o histórico de anos anteriores, assim ao trabalhar com datas no passado, você consegue saber o offset correto daquela época. E de qualquer forma, essas regras mudam o tempo todo, e nada garante que o governo não vá mudar de ideia no futuro e volte a adotar o horário de verão.*</sup>

Repare que o *offset* (a diferença com relação a UTC) mudou de `-03:00` para `-02:00`, mas o *timezone* continua sendo o mesmo (`America/Sao_Paulo`). Por isso que este campo com o valor `-02:00`, apesar de se chamar "time zone designator", na verdade corresponde ao *offset*. Você pode ver mais detalhes sobre isso na [wiki da tag `timezone`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tags/timezone/info), na seção "Diferenças entre *timezone* e *offset*".

---

OBS: a [outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/51940/112052) diz que esse formato é o "padrão UTC", mas não é bem isso. [**O padrão UTC é outra coisa**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/398796/112052): ele define um horário base padrão, a partir do qual todos os fuso horários do mundo se baseiam. Mas o UTC por si só **não** define um formato específico para datas e horas. Quem define o formato em questão é a norma ISO 8601.

Outro detalhe é que norma ISO 8601 admite valores "incompletos", como somente a data (`2019-08-22`), somente a hora (`14:30` - inclusive, os minutos e segundos podem ser omitidos), ou somente o ano (`2019`), ou ainda somente o mês e dia (`--08-22`).

---

#### Como obter este formato

Em PHP, você pode usar a constante [`DATE_ATOM`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetimeinterface.php#datetime.constants.atom), juntamente com o método [`DateTime::format`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php), ou com a [função `date`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php):

```php
$d = new DateTime("2015-02-12T15:20:16-02:00");
echo $d->format(DATE_ATOM); // 2015-02-12T15:20:16-02:00

echo date(DATE_ATOM, strtotime('12-02-2015 15:20:16 -02:00')); //2015-02-12T15:20:16-02:00
```

Você também poderia usar `"Y-m-d\TH:i:sP"` em vez de `DATE_ATOM`, como sugeriu [outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/406119/112052). O resultado é o mesmo do código acima. Usar esta forma seria interessante caso você precise dos formatos "incompletos", como por exemplo só a data (que seria `"Y-m-d"`) ou só a hora (`"H:i:s"`), ou a data e hora sem o *offset* (`"Y-m-d\TH:i:s"`). Mas para o formato completo, como data, hora e offset, usar `DATE_ATOM` já resolve.

Se quiser, você pode mudar o *timezone* (e consequentemente o *offset*), usando a classe [`DateTimeZone`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetimezone.php):

```php
// data no offset -02:00
$d = new DateTime("2015-02-12T15:20:16-02:00");
// converte para outro timezone
$d->setTimeZone(new DateTimeZone('Asia/Tokyo'));
echo $d->format(DATE_ATOM); // 2015-02-13T02:20:16+09:00
```

No caso, eu criei a data referente ao *offset* `-02:00` e depois converti para o *timezone* `Asia/Tokyo`. O resultado foi a data e hora correspondente, no fuso horário do Japão. Repare que, por causa disso, o *offset* mudou para `+09:00` (9 horas à frente do UTC), e a data e hora passou a ser dia 13 às 2 da manhã, pois esta é a data e hora correspondente a este mesmo instante no Japão (ou seja, enquanto era dia 12 às 15h no Brasil, no Japão era dia 13 às 2h).

Se você não especificar nenhum *timezone*, será usado o *default* que estiver configurado no seu ambiente. No meu caso, por exemplo, o *default* é `America/Sao_Paulo`, mas se eu mudá-lo para qualquer outro, este passa a ser usado (consequentemente, o *offset* também mudará):

```php
echo date_default_timezone_get(); // America/Sao_Paulo (pode não ser o mesmo no seu ambiente)
$d = new DateTime();
echo $d->format(DATE_ATOM); // 2019-08-28T14:18:58-03:00

// mudar o timezone default para o fuso da Alemanha
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Berlin');
$d = new DateTime();
echo $d->format(DATE_ATOM); // 2019-08-28T19:18:58+02:00
```

---

Como a pergunta tem a tag [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript), segue uma solução nesta linguagem (com ressalvas, leia até o final):

```js
let d = new Date("2015-02-12T15:20:16-02:00");
console.log(d.toISOString()); // 2015-02-12T17:20:16.000Z
```

O detalhe é que o método [`toISOString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toISOString) converte a data/hora para UTC. Por isso o resultado foi 17h (e não 15h), já que 15h no *offset* `-02:00` (ou seja, duas horas atrás de UTC) equivale a 17h em UTC - e repare no "**Z**" no final, que é a forma usada [para designar que está em UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Coordinated_Universal_Time_(UTC)) (outra forma é usar o *offset* zero: `+00:00`).

Se quiser a data/hora em um *offset* específico, é um pouco mais complicado. Existe o método [`getTimezoneOffset()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTimezoneOffset), que retorna o *offset* do *timezone* que está configurado no browser (que *geralmente* ele obtém do sistema operacional), e esse valor é retornado em minutos (mas com o detalhe de que ele retorna com "o sinal invertido"; por exemplo, se o *offset* for `-03:00`, ele retorna `180`, e se for `+03:00`, ele retorna `-180`).

Não fica um código muito bonito, mas enfim:

```js
let d = new Date("2015-02-12T15:20:16-02:00");
let offset = d.getTimezoneOffset();
let output = d.getFullYear() + '-' + (d.getMonth() + 1).toString().padStart(2, '0') + '-' +
  d.getDate().toString().padStart(2, '0') + 'T' +
  d.getHours().toString().padStart(2, '0') + ':' +
  d.getMinutes().toString().padStart(2, '0') + ':' +
  d.getSeconds().toString().padStart(2, '0') +
  `${ offset > 0 ? '-' : '+' }${ Math.floor(offset / 60).toString().padStart(2, '0') }:${ (offset % 60).toString().padStart(2, '0') }`;
console.log(output); // 2015-02-12T15:20:16-02:00
```

O problema é que esta solução está limitada ao *timezone* do browser. Se quiser usar outros *timezones*, uma alternativa é usar [`toLocaleString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleString), mas é uma solução bem limitada:

```js
let d = new Date("2015-02-12T15:20:16-02:00");
console.log(d.toLocaleString('sv', { timeZone: 'America/Sao_Paulo' })); // 2015-02-12 15:20:16
console.log(d.toLocaleString('sv', { timeZone: 'Asia/Tokyo' })); // 2015-02-13 02:20:16
```

Eu usei o [*locale* `sv` (Sueco)](http://www.localeplanet.com/icu/sv/index.html), que usa um formato próximo do ISO 8601 (bastaria substituir o espaço pela letra "T"), mas mesmo assim ele não mostra o *offset* (que teria que ser calculado à parte). Mas esta não é uma solução portável, pois depende do *locale* `sv` estar disponível/instalado no sistema, e além disso essas definições dependentes do *locale* podem mudar (não é tão comum, mas pode acontecer, como explicado [na parte final desta resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/408649/112052)).

---

Outra opção seria usar a biblioteca [Moment Timezone](https://momentjs.com/timezone/). Com ela é possível converter a data para qualquer outro *timezone*:

```js
let d = moment.tz('2015-02-12T15:20:16-02:00', 'America/Sao_Paulo');
console.log(d.format('YYYY-MM-DD[T]HH:mm:ssZ')); // 2015-02-12T15:20:16-02:00

// usar outro timezone
d = moment.tz('2015-02-12T15:20:16-02:00', 'Asia/Tokyo');
console.log(d.format('YYYY-MM-DD[T]HH:mm:ssZ')); // 2015-02-13T02:20:16+09:00
```

```html
<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment-timezone-with-data.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Para obter uma data no formato "AAAA-MM-DDThh:mm:ssTZD" em PHP faço assim:

```
<?php echo date("Y-m-d\TH:i:sP"); ?>
```

Caso precise usar a data oriunda de uma Variável, ficaria da seguinte forma:

```
$data = "2019-08-10";
echo date("$data\TH:i:sP");
```