# Como converter uma data para esse formato em PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, data

Alguém pode me dizer que tipo de data é esse formato?

```
2013-09-17T05:59:00+01:00
```

Eu tenho no banco de dados um campo do tipo timestamp ou date. Como converter o valor dele para esse formato usando PHP?

Comment: Essa data precisa aparecer assim no php?

Comment: O formato da data e [ISO 8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601).

Comment: Acho que não ficou claro a edição feita. Eu tive que abrir o histórico para entender a pergunta. De qualquer forma, veja se [esta pergunta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/51935/formato-das-datas-numa-nf-e) te ajuda em algo.

Comment: Esta pergunta está sendo debatida [aqui](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/2684/edi%C3%A7%C3%A3o-de-pergunta-mal-elaborada). E @KaduAmaral, isso é bem pertinente a você.

Comment: Valeu @VictorStafusa, vi lá o debate, e comentei lá.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Você pode obter uma data neste formato, a partir de um registro do seu banco de dados `MySQL`, desta forma:

```
echo date("Y-m-d\TH:m:sP", strtotime($db_date));
```

Onde a variável `$db_date` é o campo que você vai buscar do seu banco de dados (independente do tipo *date* ou *timestamp*) e a saída é exatamente essa que você colocou em sua pergunta.

Na documentação do `PHP` para a função [`date()`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.date.php) você encontra todos estes formatos que eu utilizei no primeiro parâmetro. No segundo parâmetro, eu apenas converti sua data para *[timestamp Unix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time)* através da função [`strtotime()`](http://php.net/strtotime).

---

Bem como o [*rray* citou aqui](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2684/edi%C3%A7%C3%A3o-de-pergunta-mal-elaborada#comment9384_2684), uma forma mais simplificada é utilizando o parâmetro `c`, que já retorna uma data no formato [`ISO 8601`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601):

```
echo date("c", strtotime($db_date));
```