# Como converter date time para formato ISO 8601 em PHP?

Tags: php, datetime

Tenho o seguinte formato: `2018-10-23T12:05:18.18UTC0TUE`

Preciso transformar em `2013-06-28T08:54:00.000-03:00` (formato iso 8601).

Tem algo especifico no php que me auxilie a transformar nesse datetime?

O que seria  esse `000-03:00` ?

Comment: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/26976/buscar-data-7-dias-antes-da-data-actual-php/26982#26982

Comment: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/59580/como-converter-uma-data-para-esse-formato-em-php/59600#59600

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basta iniciar o construtor do `DateTime` passando sua string como parâmetro:

```
$date = new DateTime('2018-10-23T12:05:18.18UTC0TUE')
```

E usar o método `DateTime::format` para formatar em `ISO8601`

```
$date->format(DateTime::ISO8601);
```

É possível usar a função `date` também:

```
date(DATE_ISO8601, strtotime('2018-10-23T12:05:18.18UTC0TUE'))
```

> O que seria esse `000-03:00`?

O `000-03:00` na verdade são duas coisas juntas. O `000` é o final do milisegundos da sua data.

O `-03:00` já é referente ao timezone da sua data.

Se você usar a função `DateTime::getTimezone()`, você consegue obter o objeto `DateTimezone` da sua data.

Veja:

```
$date->getTimezone();
```

O resultado é:

```
DateTimeZone Object
(
    [timezone_type] => 3
    [timezone] => UTC
)
```

De acordo com o [Wikipédia](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tempo_Universal_Coordenado):

> [...] é o fuso horário de referência a partir do qual se calculam todas as outras zonas horárias do mundo.

Confira umas constantes de formatação de data na [documentação](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/class.datetime.php#datetime.constants.iso8601)