# Existe timezone para Brasília?

Tags: php, mysql, timezone

Estou desenvolvendo uma app em PHP. E preciso setar o timezone para Brasília. Porém na documentação php tenho:

```
$timezones = array(
'AC' => 'America/Rio_branco',   'AL' => 'America/Maceio',
'AP' => 'America/Belem',        'AM' => 'America/Manaus',
'BA' => 'America/Bahia',        'CE' => 'America/Fortaleza',
'DF' => 'America/Sao_Paulo',    'ES' => 'America/Sao_Paulo',
'GO' => 'America/Sao_Paulo',    'MA' => 'America/Fortaleza',
'MT' => 'America/Cuiaba',       'MS' => 'America/Campo_Grande',
'MG' => 'America/Sao_Paulo',    'PR' => 'America/Sao_Paulo',
'PB' => 'America/Fortaleza',    'PA' => 'America/Belem',
'PE' => 'America/Recife',       'PI' => 'America/Fortaleza',
'RJ' => 'America/Sao_Paulo',    'RN' => 'America/Fortaleza',
'RS' => 'America/Sao_Paulo',    'RO' => 'America/Porto_Velho',
'RR' => 'America/Boa_Vista',    'SC' => 'America/Sao_Paulo',
'SE' => 'America/Maceio',       'SP' => 'America/Sao_Paulo',
'TO' => 'America/Araguaia',     
);
```

Como devo proceder ?

Consultei esta fonte: https://secure.php.net/manual/pt_BR/timezones.america.php

Comment: Na prática é a mesma de São Paulo... gmt-3 com horário de verão

Comment: Seguindo seu array, pelo estado, está correto 'DF' => date_default_timezone_set('America/Sao_Paulo');

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use a de SP que é a mesma coisa:

```
date_default_timezone_set('America/Sao_Paulo');
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/Date/TimeZoneSp.php).

[Costuma-se adotar a cidade mais populosa da região como referência](https://data.iana.org/time-zones/tz-link.html#tzdb). Não precisa ter uma cidade por país e pode ter várias cidades selecionadas na mesma região. Não é adotada a capital porque ela pode mudar, ainda que raramente aconteça, se mudar é um transtorno.

Comment: Sempre achei esquisito que a capital do país não tenha uma específica, mesmo que seja só simbólico.

Comment: @Gabe O critério da IANA é a cidade mais populosa, pode notar nos outros TZs ;) _"Usually the most populous city in a region is chosen to represent the entire time zone, although other cities may be selected if they are more widely known or result in a less ambiguous name"_ https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tz_database (citation needed x 2)

Comment: @Bacco Aaaah, tá. Não deixa de ser esquisito, mas pelo menos tem um critério!

Comment: Cara, o Acre tem :D

Comment: @WallaceMaxters Não, o Acre nada tem a ver com isto, Rio Branco é a cidade mais populosa daquela região, completamente dentro dos critérios.

Answer (score -1):

Use: date_default_timezone_set('America/Sao_Paulo');

Depois Declare uma variável:
Assim: $dtHExata = date('Y-m-d H:i');

Agora Basta usar a variável.