# Converter string de data para o formato ISO 8601 (com "T" e "Z")

Tags: python, data, datetime

Com uma data em string no formato `01/01/2018 13:00:40`, como eu poderia convertê-la para o formato ISO 8601 utilizando o `"T"` e `"Z"`?

Exemplo: `2018-01-01T13:00:40Z`

Consegui da seguinte maneira:

```
datetime.strftime(
    datetime.strptime("01/01/2018 13:00:40", "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S"),
    "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ"
)
```

Mas não acredito que seja a melhor maneira, existe algum outro método para essa conversão?

Comment: Um detalhe: o `Z` no final [indica que a data está em UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Coordinated_Universal_Time_(UTC)). Então é importante saber em qual timezone está a data de entrada. Por exemplo, se `01/01/2018 13:00:40` é uma data e hora no horário de Brasília, ao converter para UTC ela vira `2018-01-01T15:00:40Z` (em 1 de janeiro está em horário de verão, portanto 2 horas antes de UTC -> 13h em Brasília = 15h UTC (`Z`)). Sem saber qual o timezone da data de entrada, não há como saber o valor correspondente em UTC - não é só colocar um "Z" no final e pronto :-)

Answer (score 3):

É, para definir um objeto do tipo data, não há muito o que fazer. Como sua data não está em nenhum formato previsto na ISO, você precisa defini-lo manualmente, tal como fez.

```
date = datetime.strptime('15/03/2018 13:00:40', '%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S')
```

Porém, o formato desejado faz parte da ISO e já possui métodos nativos que lidam com ele:

```
print( date.isoformat() )  # 2018-01-01T13:00:40
```

Então só pelo fato de você poder usar `isoformat()` ao invés de `strftime` já simplifica seu código.

Se a entrada for sempre no horário de Brasília, você pode configurar, por defeito, a zona de horário substituindo o campo `tzinfo` do objeto `date`:

```
tzone = timezone(timedelta(hours=-3))
date = datetime.strptime('15/03/2018 13:00:40', '%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S')
date = date.replace(tzinfo=tzone)

print( date.isoformat() )  # 2018-03-15T13:00:40-03:00
```

Comment: Obrigado pela explicação Anderson, a dúvida de como incluir o "T" e o "Z" no formato ainda continua.
No seu exemplo com `isoformat()` (que eu já havia tentado) é apenas incluido o `"T"` e não o `"Z"`

Answer (score 2):

O formato para o qual você quer converter (com o "T" e o "Z") é definido pela [norma ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601). E o "Z" no final [indica que a data e hora está em UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Coordinated_Universal_Time_(UTC)).

O problema é que na string só temos a data e hora, então não tem como converter para UTC **sem assumir algumas premissas arbitrárias** (que impactarão diretamente no resultado final).

---

Explicando um pouco melhor: quando a string só tem a data e hora, o [`datetime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime) retornado por [`strptime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime) é chamado de ["*naive*"](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#aware-and-naive-objects) (em tradução literal, "ingênuo"), que é quando ele não tem informações sobre o *timezone* (fuso horário).

No seu caso, a string `"01/01/2018 13:00:40"` gera um `datetime` correspondente a 1 de janeiro de 2018, às 13:00:40. Mas em qual timezone? Não dá para saber, pois o `datetime` gerado é *naive*. Isso pode ser verificado usando as [regras descritas na documentação](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#determining-if-an-object-is-aware-or-naive):

```
from datetime import datetime

dt = datetime.strptime("01/01/2018 13:00:40", "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S")
# verificar se é naive
print(dt.tzinfo is None or dt.tzinfo.utcoffset(dt) is None) # True
```

No caso, o [`tzinfo`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.tzinfo) é a informação sobre o timezone.

Como o `datetime` não possui informação sobre o timezone, não temos como saber qual o valor correspondente em UTC. Pois em cada parte do mundo (em cada timezone/fuso-horário), o instante correspondente a 1 de janeiro de 2018 às 13h ocorreu um momento diferente, e portanto a data e hora em UTC será diferente.

Por exemplo, se consideramos "1 de janeiro de 2018 às 13:00:40 **no Horário de Brasília**", então ao converter para UTC o resultado deve ser "2018-01-01T15:00:40Z" - repare que o horário em UTC é 15h, já que em janeiro de 2018 o Horário de Brasília estava em horário de verão, e portanto 2 horas a menos que UTC.

Mas se considerarmos "1 de janeiro de 2018 às 13:00:40 **no fuso horário do Japão**", ao converter para UTC o resultado seria "2018-01-01T04:00:40Z" (o horário mudou para 4 da manhã), pois o fuso do Japão está 9 horas à frente do UTC.

E dependendo do lugar, até mesmo o dia e mês podem ser diferentes. "1 de janeiro de 2018 às 13:00:40 no [fuso horário de Samoa](https://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/samoa/apia)" em UTC é "2017-12-31T23:00:40Z" (**31 de dezembro de 2017**, às 23:00:40), e "1 de janeiro de 2018 às 13:00:40 no [fuso horário de Niue](https://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/niue)" (um [pequeno país insular](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Niue) do Pacífico Sul) em UTC é "2018-01-02T00:00:40Z" (meia-noite do dia **2** de janeiro de 2018).

Ou seja, dependendo do timezone ao qual a data e hora se referem, o resultado em UTC será diferente. E como a string `"01/01/2018 13:00:40"` não tem nenhuma informação sobre o timezone, as opções são: escolher um arbitrariamente, ou usar o *default* que estiver configurado no sistema.

---

### Considerar o timezone do sistema

Podemos simplesmente usar o [método `astimezone`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.astimezone), passando como parâmetro um timezone correspondente a UTC. Segundo a documentação: "*If self is naive, it is presumed to represent time in the system timezone*"; ou seja, quando o `datetime` for *naive* (o que é o nosso caso), assume-se que a data e hora estão no "timezone do sistema".

Para obter um timezone correspondente a UTC temos duas opções. A primeira é construir um [objeto `timezone`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.timezone), passando como parâmetros o *offset* (a diferença com relação a UTC) e o nome. Como quero um timezone que corresponde a UTC, o *offset* é zero (e para isso usamos um [`timedelta`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#timedelta-objects)). E o nome é "Z", pois aí posso usar o formato `%Z` (que [segundo a documentação](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-format-codes), imprime o nome do timezone):

```
from datetime import datetime, timezone, timedelta

dt = datetime.strptime("01/01/2018 13:00:40", "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S")
dt = dt.astimezone(timezone(timedelta(hours=0), 'Z'))
print(dt.strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%Z"))
```

Eu não usei o [método `isoformat`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.isoformat) porque em vez do "Z", ele imprime o offset (no caso, "+00:00", e aí eu teria que usar um `replace('+00:00', 'Z')`). Em vez disso, usei uma string de formatação com os campos específicos, incluindo o `%Z` para mostrar o nome que defini no construtor de `timezone`.

---

Outra opção (para Python <= 3.8) é usar o [módulo `pytz`](https://pypi.org/project/pytz/), que possui suporte aos [timezones da IANA](https://www.iana.org/time-zones) (muitíssimo recomendado se você quiser se manter atualizado quanto às constantes mudanças nos timezones, como por exemplo, as regras de horário de verão, [que mudam o tempo todo](https://www.timeanddate.com/news/time/)). Ele já possui um timezone específico para UTC:

```
import pytz
from datetime import datetime

dt = datetime.strptime("01/01/2018 13:00:40", "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S")
dt = dt.astimezone(pytz.utc)
print(dt.strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%Z").replace('UTC', 'Z'))
```

O problema é que o nome do timezone é "UTC" (e não "Z"), e testando todas as opções disponíveis para `strftime`, nenhuma retornou "Z". Então o jeito foi fazer um `replace` no final.

---

Uma desvantagem desta solução é que você fica completamente dependente do timezone do sistema, e o resultado pode variar muito. Por exemplo, na minha máquina o resultado foi `2018-01-01T15:00:40Z` (15h em vez de 13h), já que no meu sistema o timezone corresponde ao Horário de Brasília. Mas rodando no [IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/nvVgKM) e no [Repl.it](https://repl.it/@hkotsubo/ExpertRepentantParameter#main.py), o resultado foi `2018-01-01T13:00:40Z` (13h, provavelmente porque esses ambientes estão configurados com UTC).

---

Outro teste para mostrar como o resultado varia conforme a configuração é ficar mudando o timezone do ambiente. Por exemplo, no Linux você pode setar a [variável `TZ`](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/TZ-Variable.html) para mudar o timezone. No caso, eu rodei o seguinte script (em um arquivo chamado `date_test.py`):

```
import pytz
from datetime import datetime, timezone, timedelta

dt = datetime.strptime("01/01/2018 13:00:40", "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S")
print('--- sem timezone')
print(dt.strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%Z"))

print('--- converter para UTC')
dt = datetime.strptime("01/01/2018 13:00:40", "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S")
dt = dt.astimezone(pytz.utc)
print(dt.strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%Z").replace('UTC', 'Z'))

print('--- converter para UTC com timedelta')
dt = datetime.strptime("01/01/2018 13:00:40", "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S")
dt = dt.astimezone(timezone(timedelta(hours=0), 'Z'))
print(dt.strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%Z"))
```

Na linha de comando, eu setei a variável `TZ` para diferentes timezones:

```
$ TZ=Pacific/Niue python3 date_test.py
--- sem timezone
2018-01-01T13:00:40
--- converter para UTC
2018-01-02T00:00:40Z
--- converter para UTC com timedelta
2018-01-02T00:00:40Z

$ TZ=America/Sao_Paulo python3 date_test.py
--- sem timezone
2018-01-01T13:00:40
--- converter para UTC
2018-01-01T15:00:40Z
--- converter para UTC com timedelta
2018-01-01T15:00:40Z

$ TZ=Asia/Tokyo python3 date_test.py
--- sem timezone
2018-01-01T13:00:40
--- converter para UTC
2018-01-01T04:00:40Z
--- converter para UTC com timedelta
2018-01-01T04:00:40Z

$ TZ=Pacific/Apia python3 date_test.py
--- sem timezone
2018-01-01T13:00:40
--- converter para UTC
2017-12-31T23:00:40Z
--- converter para UTC com timedelta
2017-12-31T23:00:40Z
```

Repare como cada timezone resulta em um valor diferente (confirmando o que já foi explicado anteriormente).

Para evitar isso, outra solução seria considerar que a string refere-se a um timezone específico.

---

### Considerar um timezone específico antes de converter para UTC

Neste caso, vou usar o módulo `pytz` (recomendável para Python <= 3.8 - ao final também falo da alternativa para Python >= 3.9), já que ele possui suporte aos timezones da IANA (que são os nomes no formato `Continente/Regiao` usados no exemplo anterior).

A vantagem do `pytz` é que não precisamos usar `timedelta`, já que isso é extremamente propenso a erros. Existe uma explicação mais detalhada [nesta resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/349822/112052) (na seção "Não use `timedelta`"), mas basicamente: um identificador como `America/Sao_Paulo` possui todo o histórico de alterações deste timezone, como por exemplo as mudanças de horário de verão (quando ocorreram, e qual o *offset* antes e depois da mudança).

Por exemplo, no timezone `America/Sao_Paulo` (que [corresponde ao Horário de Brasília](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/259124/112052)), durante o horário de verão o *offset* é `-02:00` (2 horas a menos que UTC), mas durante o horário "normal" é `-03:00` (3 horas a menos que UTC). Só que as regras variam muito de um ano para outro (em cada ano, o horário de verão começa e termina em uma data diferente, fora os anos em que não teve). Se você fosse usar `timedelta`, teria que saber se a data e hora que está manipulando corresponde ao horário de verão ou não, caso contrário seria usado o valor incorreto (e consequentemente a conversão para UTC ficaria errada). Mas usando o identificador `America/Sao_Paulo`, o `pytz` já consulta o histórico do timezone e usa o valor correto (ele faz o "trabalho sujo" para você).

A desvantagem do `pytz` já vimos acima (tem que fazer o `replace`), mas dadas as vantagens (não precisar "adivinhar" o *offset* correto de cada timezone em cada época), nesse caso eu acho perfeitamente aceitável.

O código fica assim:

```
from datetime import datetime
import pytz

dt = datetime.strptime("01/01/2018 13:00:40", "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S")
# setar o timezone (sem conversão)
dt = pytz.timezone('America/Sao_Paulo').localize(dt)
# converter para UTC
dt = dt.astimezone(pytz.utc)
print(dt.strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%Z").replace('UTC', 'Z'))
```

Neste caso, eu assumi que a string `"01/01/2018 13:00:40"` corresponde a uma data e hora no Horário de Brasília. **Esta é a premissa arbitrária** que mencionei no início. Como não temos nenhuma informação sobre o timezone ao qual a string se refere, temos que assumir algum timezone específico, a fim de não depender do que estiver configurado no sistema (se você tiver esta informação sobre o timezone em algum lugar, use o correto em vez de `America/Sao_Paulo`).

Então primeiro eu seto o timezone no `datetime` (que deixa de ser *naive*), e depois eu converto para UTC. Agora o retorno **sempre** é `2018-01-01T15:00:40Z`, independente do timezone que estiver configurado no sistema (veja no [IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/2S9TP0) e no [Repl.it](https://repl.it/@hkotsubo/EnlightenedEqualAddition#main.py), por exemplo). Se eu fizer o teste acima mudando a variável `TZ`, o resultado continua sendo `2018-01-01T15:00:40Z`, pois agora o código sempre assume que a data e hora está no Horário de Brasília antes de converter para UTC (não depende mais do timezone do sistema).

---

Obs: se você assumir que a string representa uma data e hora em UTC, então bastaria fazer:

```
dt = datetime.strptime("01/01/2018 13:00:40", "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S")
dt = pytz.utc.localize(dt)
print(dt.strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%Z").replace('UTC', 'Z'))
```

Agora o retorno sempre será `2018-01-01T13:00:40Z`, independente do timezone do sistema.

> *Obviamente que **neste caso específico** você até poderia usar `isoformat()` ou `dt.strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S")` e concatenar o "Z", mas eu ainda prefiro usar `localize`, pois o `datetime` deixa de ser naive e passa a representar uma data e hora em UTC (o que evita erros caso você precise convertê-la para outro timezone, por exemplo).*

---

#### Python >= 3.9

A partir do Python 3.9 é possível usar o [módulo `zoneinfo`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zoneinfo.html), que também possui suporte aos timezones da IANA. Seu funcionamento é similar ao `pytz`.

Por exemplo, para o caso de considerar que a data está em um timezone específico antes de converter para UTC:

```
from datetime import datetime
from zoneinfo import ZoneInfo

# considerar que a data está no timezone America/Sao_Paulo
dt = datetime.strptime("01/01/2018 13:00:40", "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S").replace(tzinfo=ZoneInfo('America/Sao_Paulo'))
# converter para UTC
dt = dt.astimezone(ZoneInfo('UTC'))
print(dt.strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%Z").replace('UTC', 'Z')) # 2018-01-01T15:00:40Z
```

Ou, se quer considerar que a data já está em UTC:

```
from datetime import datetime
from zoneinfo import ZoneInfo

dt = datetime.strptime("01/01/2018 13:00:40", "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S").replace(tzinfo=ZoneInfo('UTC'))
print(dt.strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%Z").replace('UTC', 'Z')) # 2018-01-01T13:00:40Z
```