# Converter timestamp para data/hora

Tags: python, data, datetime, timestamp

Eu estou consultando uma API e ela me retorna a data da seguinte forma:

```
"timestamp":"1444253422.348340958"
```

Como converter essa informação em data e hora utilizando Python?

Comment: Maurício, a resposta que usa `timedelta` nem sempre funcionará corretamente. Se o timestamp recebido corresponder a uma data que cai no horário de verão, e/ou se o servidor estiver configurado com um timezone que não seja UTC, usar o `timedelta` trará resultados incorretos - veja a [minha resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/349822/112052) para mais detalhes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Este formato de data se chama Unix time. É o número de segundos passados desde 01/01/1970 emm UTC/GMT.

Usando a biblioteca [datetime](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html) você pode fazer esta conversão. Você vai transformar esse valor em um objeto data que pode ser manipulado de várias formas usando o datetime. A data pode ser convertida para BRT utilizando métodos do datetime, <s>mas aconselho fazer a conversão você mesmo.</s> **Ver observação**

```
from datetime import datetime
from datetime import timedelta

objeto_data = datetime.fromtimestamp(1444253422.348340958)
print(objeto_data)
data_br = objeto_data - timedelta(hours=3)   #Cuidado com esta conversão. Leia a observação abaixo.
print(data_br)  #imprimir desse jeito fica horrivel, mas voce pode separar cada informacao e imprimir como quiser
texto = str(data_br.day) + "/" + str(data_br.month) + "/" + str(data_br.year) + "  BRT  " + str(data_br.hour) + ":" + str(data_br.minute)
print(texto)
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Este provavelmente não é o melhor modo de imprimir a data e hora, mas o importante é você converter o valor em Unix time para um objeto de data manipulável. Com isto você tem toda a flexibilidade da biblioteca datetime.

**-------------------------------------------------------------------**

**OBS:** Caso necessite de utilizar fuso horário, veja a resposta abaixo a respeito da biblioteca pytz

Comment: Usar `timedelta` nem sempre trará o "horário brasileiro" correto, veja [minha resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/349822/112052) para mais detalhes. Resumindo, `fromtimestamp` usa o timezone default da máquina e nem sempre será UTC. Na minha máquina, por exemplo, o resultado deste código foi `7/10/2015  BRT  15:30` (sendo que o timestamp em questão corresponde a **18:30** no horário de Brasília)

Comment: Outro detalhe é que não é somente o Brasil que usa o offset -03:00, há [vários outros países](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_UTC_time_offsets#UTC%E2%88%9203:00,_P) que também usam. Por isso colocar um "BRT" fixo no código é impreciso (sem contar que ignora o horário de verão, quando a diferença é de 2 horas e a abreviação muda p/ "BRST" - usando timezones vc evita esses problemas). E o horário do seu resultado foi 15:30, sendo que o timestamp 1444253422 corresponde a [18:30 no horário de Brasília](https://www.epochconverter.com/timezones?q=1444253422&tz=America%2FSao_Paulo).

Comment: O primeiro comentário foi bastante útil, recebeu meu upvote. Sua resposta foi boa, recebeu meu upvote também e até me fez editar a minha, mas agora você está só chutando cachorro morto, não acha? A pergunta tratava de converter um timestamp em data e eu mostrei como converter para um objeto manipulável e até o jeito mais noob-friendly de imprimir o resultado em string. Se no programa final o usuário tiver que imprimir "BRST" ou "BRT" cabe a ele saber qual usar. Não é pra copiar e colar resposta do SO no código sem aprender.

Comment: Desculpe, só quis apontar os pontos que muita gente desconsidera e acho importantes, datas são um assunto mais complexo do que parece e soluções mais "simples" tendem a não estar 100% corretas e não funcionar em todos as situações, por não cobrirem todos os casos. Não tive a intenção de "chutar" ninguém. Mas já que mencionou, usando timezones vc não precisa se preocupar em saber/adivinhar se será BRT ou BRST, pois o próprio timezone já possui esta informação. Sem stress :-)

Answer (score 11):

Este número é um [timestamp](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/70473/112052), que representa a quantidade de tempo decorrida a partir do [*Unix Epoch*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) (`1970-01-01T00:00Z` - 1 de janeiro de 1970 à meia-noite em [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time)).

Normalmente usa-se um valor em segundos ou milissegundos, e no seu caso, está em segundos. Ou seja, é um valor que representa 1.444.253.422,348340958 segundos depois do Unix Epoch. (se estivesse em milissegundos, [corresponderia a uma data em 1970](https://ideone.com/0H3nlL), então acho mais provável que esteja em segundos mesmo).

Como você quer transformar isso em uma data e hora, há um detalhe que deve levar em conta. O timestamp representa um ponto na linha do tempo: um único instante que é o mesmo no mundo todo. Só que este mesmo instante corresponde a uma data e hora diferentes, dependendo do timezone (fuso-horário). Por exemplo, o timestamp `1444253422.348340958` corresponde aos seguintes dias e horários:

- Em São Paulo: 7 de outubro de 2015, às 18:30:22.348340958
- Em Londres: 7 de outubro de 2015, às 22:30:22.348340958
- Em Tóquio: **8** de outubro de 2015, às 06:30:22.348340958
- Em UTC: 7 de outubro de 2015, às 21:30:22.348340958

Repare que o horário é diferente em cada parte do mundo, e em Tóquio até mesmo o dia é diferente (interessante notar também que em Londres não é o mesmo horário que UTC - um *mito* comum - pois neste dia [a Inglaterra estava em horário de verão](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/zone/uk/london?year=2015)).

Portanto, se você quer converter um timestamp para uma data e hora específicas, **você precisa saber qual timezone será utilizado**.

---

### Módulos `datetime` e `pytz`

Usando o [módulo `datetime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html), é possível converter o timestamp para uma data e hora. E para trabalhar com timezones, até o Python 3.8, sugiro o [módulo `pytz`](https://pypi.org/project/pytz/), que possui suporte aos [timezones da IANA](https://www.iana.org/time-zones) (logo mais explico a solução para Python >= 3.9 e porque estes são melhores do que usar `timedelta`).

Mas antes você precisa transformar a string `"1444253422.348340958"` em número. Como não é um número inteiro, podemos usar [`float`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=float#float), sem esquecer de capturar o [`ValueError`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#ValueError) caso a string não seja um número.

Em seguida eu uso [`datetime.fromtimestamp`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.fromtimestamp), passando dois parâmetros:

- o valor do timestamp (e por sorte este método aceita valores "com vírgula", portanto podemos passar o valor do `float` diretamente)
- o timezone que será usado para converter o timestamp para uma data e hora específicas

```
from datetime import datetime
from pytz import timezone

try:
    # converter string para número
    timestamp = float("1444253422.348340958")

    # converter o timestamp para uma data e hora em um timezone específico
    dt = datetime.fromtimestamp(timestamp, tz = timezone("Asia/Tokyo"))
    print(dt) # 2015-10-08 06:30:22.348341+09:00
    # se quiser mostrar em outro formato
    print(dt.strftime("%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S.%f %z")) # 08/10/2015 06:30:22.348341 +0900

    # converter para outro timezone
    dt = dt.astimezone(timezone("Europe/London"))
    print(dt) # 2015-10-07 22:30:22.348341+01:00
    print(dt.strftime("%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S.%f %z")) # 07/10/2015 22:30:22.348341 +0100
except ValueError:
    print("não foi possível converter o valor do timestamp para um número")
```

Neste exemplo eu usei `Asia/Tokyo`, o que fez com que a data e hora fosse "8 de outubro de 2015 às 06:30.22.348341" (a API possui precisão de microssegundos, ou seja, os 3 últimos dígitos da fração de segundos são perdidos). Em seguida eu converti para `Europe/London`, o que mudou tanto o dia quanto a hora (isso é para mostrar que o mesmo timestamp de fato corresponde a uma data e hora diferentes, dependendo do timezone utilizado). Repare também nos valores `+09:00` e `+01:00`: estes são os [*offsets*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC_offset) (a diferença com relação a UTC), que no caso indicam que estes horários estão respectivamente 9 horas e 1 hora à frente do UTC.

E se eu não especificar o timezone no método `fromtimestamp`?

```
print(datetime.fromtimestamp(timestamp))
```

Na minha máquina o resultado foi `2015-10-07 18:30:22.348341`, mas este resultado pode variar de acordo com o timezone *default* utilizado internamente (no meu caso, pelo valor retornado, parece ser `America/Sao_Paulo` - o timezone correspondente ao horário oficial de Brasília). Mas rodando no [Ideone.com](https://ideone.com/kpqK6z), por exemplo, o resultado foi `2015-10-07 21:30:22.348341` (pois provavelmente lá o timezone está configurado como UTC).

Por isso é importante passar um timezone específico, pois o timestamp corresponde a uma data e hora diferentes em cada lugar do mundo. Ao usar `fromtimestamp` e sem especificar um timezone, você perde o controle sobre a data/hora retornada.

Os nomes de timezones, como `America/Sao_Paulo`, `Europe/London` e `Asia/Tokyo`, seguem o padrão da [IANA](https://www.iana.org/time-zones), e você pode ver a lista completa usando [`all_timezones`](https://pythonhosted.org/pytz/#helpers):

```
import pytz

print(pytz.all_timezones)
```

Isso imprime uma lista com vários nomes (mais de 500), e você pode escolher o mais adequado para a sua situação. Para o horário oficial de Brasília, você pode usar `America/Sao_Paulo` (que possui inclusive as regras do horário de verão), mas caso queira o fuso do Nordeste (que atualmente não usa horário de verão) pode usar `America/Recife` ou `America/Bahia`, por exemplo. A IANA disponibiliza seus arquivos no GitHub, então você também pode consultar todos os timezones do Brasil (todas as linhas que começam com "BR" [neste arquivo](https://github.com/eggert/tz/blob/2018g/zone1970.tab#L85)) e escolher o que precisa.

O próprio `pytz` também possui esta informação. Basta acessar o dicionário [`country_timezones`](https://pythonhosted.org/pytz/#country-information), passando como chave o código do país (duas letras, de acordo com a [ISO 3166](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1#Current_codes)). No caso, o código do Brasil é "BR", então para saber todos os timezones do Brasil, basta fazer:

```
print(pytz.country_timezones['BR'])
```

Isso retorna uma lista com todos os nomes de timezones do Brasil. Na versão que estou usando atualmente (pytz 2018.7), o retorno foi:

> ['America/Noronha', 'America/Belem', 'America/Fortaleza', 'America/Recife', 'America/Araguaina', 'America/Maceio', 'America/Bahia', 'America/Sao_Paulo', 'America/Campo_Grande', 'America/Cuiaba', 'America/Santarem', 'America/Porto_Velho', 'America/Boa_Vista', 'America/Manaus', 'America/Eirunepe', 'America/Rio_Branco']

Escolha o que melhor se adequar ao que você precisa. Exemplo:

```
dt = datetime.fromtimestamp(timestamp, tz = timezone("America/Sao_Paulo"))
print(dt)  # 2015-10-07 18:30:22.348341-03:00
# se quiser mostrar em outro formato
print(dt.strftime("%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S.%f %z"))  # 07/10/2015 18:30:22.348341 -0300
```

Neste caso, eu obtive a data e hora no horário de Brasília (`America/Sao_Paulo`).

---

#### Python >= 3.9

A partir do Python 3.9 você pode usar o [módulo `zoneinfo`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zoneinfo.html), que já vem instalado nativamente e possui suporte aos timezones da IANA. O código acima ficaria praticamente igual, bastando substituir o `timezone` do `pytz` por `ZoneInfo`:

```
from datetime import datetime
from zoneinfo import ZoneInfo

try:
    # converter string para número
    timestamp = float("1444253422.348340958")

    # converter o timestamp para uma data e hora em um timezone específico
    dt = datetime.fromtimestamp(timestamp, tz = ZoneInfo("Asia/Tokyo"))
    print(dt) # 2015-10-08 06:30:22.348341+09:00
    # se quiser mostrar em outro formato
    print(dt.strftime("%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S.%f %z")) # 08/10/2015 06:30:22.348341 +0900

    # converter para outro timezone
    dt = dt.astimezone(ZoneInfo("Europe/London"))
    print(dt) # 2015-10-07 22:30:22.348341+01:00
    print(dt.strftime("%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S.%f %z")) # 07/10/2015 22:30:22.348341 +0100

    # usar o timezone do Horário de Brasília
    dt = datetime.fromtimestamp(timestamp, tz = ZoneInfo("America/Sao_Paulo"))
    print(dt)  # 2015-10-07 18:30:22.348341-03:00
    # se quiser mostrar em outro formato
    print(dt.strftime("%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S.%f %z"))  # 07/10/2015 18:30:22.348341 -0300
except ValueError:
    print("não foi possível converter o valor do timestamp para um número")
```

E para ver todos os timezones disponíveis, basta usar [`zoneinfo.available_timezones`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zoneinfo.html#zoneinfo.available_timezones):

```
from zoneinfo import available_timezones

print(available_timezones())
```

---

## Não use `timedelta`

[Uma das respostas](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/349795/112052) sugere o uso de [`timedelta`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#timedelta-objects) para subtrair 3 horas da data e com isso obter o "fuso horário brasileiro". Isso só funciona se `fromtimestamp` retornar a data e hora em UTC (o que já vimos que não é garantido se você não especificar o timezone), **e** se o timestamp corresponde a uma data/hora em que o Brasil não está em horário de verão (pois durante o horário de verão o offset passa a ser de `-02:00`, então deveriam ser subtraídas somente 2 horas).

O problema é que é muito difícil determinar o valor exato a ser subtraído de UTC, já que as regras do horário de verão mudam o tempo todo. No Brasil, por exemplo: até 2017, o horário de verão começava no terceiro domingo de outubro, mas a partir de 2018, [passou a começar no primeiro domingo de novembro](https://g1.globo.com/economia/noticia/horario-de-verao-comecara-em-novembro-e-nao-mais-em-outubro-a-partir-de-2018-informa-planalto.ghtml). E será assim "para sempre", ou seja, até que mude de novo - aliás, já mudou, [o Brasil não terá horário de verão em 2019](http://www.planalto.gov.br/ccivil_03/_ato2019-2022/2019/decreto/D9772.htm) (e será assim até que mude de novo).

Além disso, não é todo o país que adotava o horário de verão. No momento em que escrevo esta resposta ([dezembro de 2018](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/change/brazil?year=2018#dst_map)), os estados do Nordeste não adotam, então eles usam o offset `-03:00` o ano todo. Já os estados do Sul/Sudeste usam `-03:00` durante parte do ano, e no horário de verão mudam para `-02:00`. E os estados do Centro-oeste usam `-03:00` no horário de verão e `-04:00` no horário "normal". Mas no Norte (Amazonas/Pará/etc), atualmente não adotam o horário de verão e usam `-04:00` o ano todo, exceto pelo Acre, que usa `-05:00` o ano todo (mas já mudou essas regras [várias vezes](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/zone/brazil/rio-branco?year=1980#tb-zone)). E não esqueça de [Fernando de Noronha](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/zone/brazil/fernando-de-noronha), que usa o offset `-02:00` o ano todo.

Enfim, usar valores fixos de `timedelta` (como `-3`, ou qualquer outro valor) é impreciso porque é preciso saber de todas essas regras (se determinada região tem horário de verão, quando começa e termina, quais os offsets usados, etc), e mesmo "o horário brasileiro" é algo difícil de definir, já que depende de qual região você está se referindo. E é aí que entra a [IANA](https://www.iana.org/time-zones): ela possui um banco de dados que já tem todo esse histórico e você não precisa se preocupar com isso. Tudo que você precisa é saber o identificador do timezone que quer usar (os nomes `America/Sao_Paulo`, `Europe/London`, etc).

Usando estes identificadores, como por exemplo `America/Sao_Paulo`, ele já saberá se no instante que o timestamp representa, aquela região está ou não em horário de verão e usará o offset correto (sem você precisar "adivinhar" e subtrair/somar `timedeltas` arbitrários).

Isso é importante porque estas regras mudam mais do que imaginamos. Atualmente `America/Recife` não adota o horário de verão, [mas nos anos 80 adotava](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/zone/brazil/recife?year=1985). E nada garante que isso não mudará no futuro, já que estas regras são definidas por governos/leis e nem sempre com justificativas técnicas. É comum justificativas como "Quero que o povo tenha mais horas de sol", e até mesmo o argumento de economia de energia e demais vantagens e desvantagens é [debatido em vários lugares](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/dst/daylight-saving-debate.html), e a todo momento, em algum lugar do mundo, [há alguém discutindo se deveria mudar ou não o horário de verão](https://www.timeanddate.com/news/time/) (ou seja, a única certeza que temos é que estas regras mudam o tempo todo).

Agora que o Brasil cancelou o horário de verão, é tentador achar que podemos usar um valor fixo de `timedelta`, mas nada garante que no futuro o governo não volte a adotá-lo. Mesmo que demore para acontecer, usar um timezone é bem mais garantido, pelos motivos já explicados acima.

Por isso há uma grande vantagem em usar o `pytz`, pois ele é atualizado conforme a IANA lança novas versões do seu banco, e estas atualizações ficam disponíveis no [PyPI](https://pypi.org/project/pytz/). Inclusive, eles [já estão cientes que o Brasil não vai ter horário de verão em 2019](https://mm.icann.org/pipermail/tz/2019-April/027880.html) e [já foi lançada uma nova versão contendo esta mudança](https://mm.icann.org/pipermail/tz/2019-July/028249.html).

---

O uso de `timedelta` é uma solução que "parece" certa porque muitos não consideram todas as regras envolvendo timezones, e acham que um valor fixo de offset é o suficiente.

Só que um offset não é o mesmo que um timezone: o offset é apenas um valor numérico fixo (a diferença com relação a UTC, como `+09:00` ou `-03:00`), enquanto um timezone (como `America/Sao_Paulo` ou `Europe/London`) possui todo o histórico de offsets de uma determinada região (os valores do offset quando é horário de verão e quando não é, os instantes exatos em que ocorrem estas mudanças, etc). Para mais informações, veja a seção "Diferenças entre timezone e offset" [na descrição da *tag* timezone](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tags/timezone/info).

Comment: +1 E na aula de hoje, *timestamps* :D

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss É, acho que me empolguei na explicação. Mas é que não é um assunto fácil - parece fácil, mas se começa a entrar nos detalhes... :-)

Answer (score 2):

Use o módulo `datetime`.

Exemplo:

```
from datetime import datetime
ts = int("1284101485")
print(datetime.utcfromtimestamp(ts).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))
```

> Fonte: [SO - Converting unix timestamp string to readable date](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3682808/5988245)

Comment: Você esta ciente que ao converter o valor que ele esta recebendo em inteiro ira causar um *ValueError* né? É bom explicar que terá que fatiar o valor.