# Converter string no formato dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm para Date

Tags: javascript, data

Como posso converter uma data que está em string para um tipo data?

Tentei fazer da seguinte forma mas não funcionou:

```
var string = "19/07/2019 14:18"
var date = new Date(string);
```

Quando dou um `console.log(date);` me mostra "data inválida".

Comment: Conforme a [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date), quando você passa uma `dataString` a *string* deverá estar uma formato reconhecido pelo método [`Date.parse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse)

Comment: Segue a solução: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/6526/como-formatar-data-no-javascript

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Você precisa passar uma string de data em uma formato válido.

De acordo com a documentação, [entre as diversas formas de instanciar uma data](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date#Parameters), existe a opção de passar uma string. Nesse caso:

> Um valor do tipo String que representa uma data. A string deverá estar uma formato reconhecido pelo método [`Date.parse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse) ([IETF-compliant RFC 2822 timestamps](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2822#page-14) e também uma [versão da ISO8601](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.1.15)).

Assim, a forma mais fácil é converter a sua string (que está no formato brasileiro), para o [formato compatível com o ISO](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.1.15). Nesse caso:

```
YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm
```

Em que:

- `YYYY` ⇒ representa o ano;
- `MM` ⇒ representa o mês;
- `DD` ⇒ representa o dia;
- `T` ⇒ representa a separação entre a "data" e a hora;
- `HH` ⇒ representa a hora do dia;
- `mm` ⇒ representa os minutos da hora.

Então, podemos criar uma função para converter a data:

```js
// A data passada deve estar no padrão:
// DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm
function toISOFormat(dateTimeString) {
  // Primeiro, dividimos a data completa em duas partes:
  const [date, time] = dateTimeString.split(' ');

  // Dividimos a data em dia, mês e ano:
  const [DD, MM, YYYY] = date.split('/');

  // Dividimos o tempo em hora e minutos:
  const [HH, mm] = time.split(':');

  // Retornamos a data formatada em um padrão compatível com ISO:
  return `${YYYY}-${MM}-${DD}T${HH}:${mm}`;
}

console.log(toISOFormat('19/07/2019 14:18'));
```

Agora que você tem o meio de converter a data, basta instanciá-la:

```js
// A data passada deve estar no padrão:
// DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm
function toISOFormat(dateTimeString) {
  // Primeiro, dividimos a data completa em duas partes:
  const [date, time] = dateTimeString.split(' ');

  // Dividimos a data em dia, mês e ano:
  const [DD, MM, YYYY] = date.split('/');

  // Dividimos o tempo em hora e minutos:
  const [HH, mm] = time.split(':');

  // Retornamos a data formatada em um padrão compatível com ISO:
  return `${YYYY}-${MM}-${DD}T${HH}:${mm}`;
}

const dateString = toISOFormat('19/07/2019 14:18');
const date = new Date(dateString);

// Testando:
console.log(date.getFullYear());
```

É importante dizer que existem muitas formas de se construir uma data no JavaScript. Essa resposta aborda somente **uma das diversas possibilidades**. Para saber mais, não deixe de consultar a [documentação do `Date` na MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date).

Comment: Por que o negativo?

Comment: minha data está nesse formato 2019-07-19 19:46:00 
porém quando uso  no console.log(new Date(stringDate)) ele me retorna data invalida 
a data está no formato correto ?

Comment: Qual o seu navegador e a versão dele? Tente instanciar a data com esse formato: `new Date('2019-07-19T19:46:00')`. Funciona?

Answer (score 4):

Como muitos já disseram, quando você passa uma string para o construtor de `Date`, a [documentação](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date#Parameters) diz que esta string deve estar em um [formato reconhecido por `Date.parse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse#Date_Time_String_Format). Qualquer outro formato pode resultar em uma data inválida ([ou em comportamento indefinido, dependente do *browser*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse#Fall-back_to_implementation-specific_date_formats)).

Dito isso, o formato que você está usando não está entre os que são citados na documentação. Uma alternativa seria transformar a string em um dos formatos reconhecidos, como já foi sugerido pelas outras respostas. Mas o construtor de `Date` também pode receber os valores numéricos diretamente, então basta extraí-los da string:

```js
let s = "19/07/2019 14:18";
let [dia, mes, ano, hora, minuto] = s.split(/[\/: ]/).map(v => parseInt(v));
let data = new Date(ano, mes - 1, dia, hora, minuto);
console.log(data);
console.log(data.getTime());
```

Usei a regex `[\/: ]` (uma barra, ou dois pontos, ou espaço) para separar todos os campos de uma vez (é meio "ingênuo", pois se a string for `"19 07:2019/14 18"`, também funcionará - se quiser ser mais restrito quanto ao formato, pode usar as opções sugeridas nas outras respostas).

Em seguida uso `map` com `parseInt` para transformar cada trecho em um número (já que o `split` retorna um array de strings) - assim você já valida que cada parte é um número, já que `parseInt` retorna `NaN` caso não receba um número, e o resultado será uma data inválida.

Repare também que tive que subtrair 1 do mês, já que nesta API os meses são indexados em zero (janeiro é zero, fevereiro é 1, etc).

Apesar disso, o construtor aceita valores aparentemente inválidos, como mês 15, dia 32, etc, e faz alguns ajustes automáticos e "não-intuitivos" (dia 32 acaba virando o dia 1 do mês seguinte, mês 12 acaba virando janeiro do ano seguinte, etc). Então se quiser, você ainda pode incluir validações a mais antes de criar a data (`if (1 <= dia && dia <= 31)`, etc) para garantir que os valores são realmente válidos.

Por fim, eu imprimo a data e também o valor de [`getTime()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTime), que retorna o respectivo [*timestamp*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/70473/112052). E aqui tem um detalhe muito importante...

---

## O que é o `Date` do JavaScript

Um `Date` do JavaScript representa na verdade um [***timestamp***](https://hkotsubo.github.io/blog/2019-05-02/o-que-e-timestamp): a quantidade de milissegundos desde o [*Unix Epoch*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) (que é `1970-01-01T00:00Z`, ou 1 de janeiro de 1970, à meia-noite, [em UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time)).

O detalhe é que o timestamp é "universal", no sentido de ser o mesmo no mundo todo (diferente dos fusos horários, que em cada parte do mundo pode ser uma data e hora diferente).

Por exemplo, na minha máquina, rodando o código acima, o retorno de `data.getTime()` foi `1563556680000`. Este timestamp representa um único instante, um ponto na linha do tempo. Este exato instante, porém, pode representar uma data e hora diferentes em cada parte do mundo:

- No Horário de Brasília, é 19 de julho de 2019, às 14:18
- No Japão, é **20** de julho de 2019, às 02:18 da manhã
- Em UTC, é 19 de julho de 2019, às 17:18

O mesmo valor de timestamp (`1563556680000`) corresponde a todas as datas e horas acima. O instante (o ponto na linha do tempo) é o mesmo, o que muda é o valor da data e hora local, de acordo com o timezone (fuso horário) que você usa.

**E por que estou dizendo tudo isso?** Por que quando eu criei o `Date` acima passando os valores de data e hora, ele usa o timezone do browser para calcular o timestamp (e o browser, por sua vez, geralmente usa o que está configurado no sistema operacional). Como meu browser está usando o Horário de Brasília, ele entende que estou criando uma data correspondente a 19/07/2019, às 14:18, neste timezone.

Mas se eu mudar o timezone (fuso horário) do meu sistema para o fuso do Japão, o JavaScript vai criar uma data correspondente a 19/07/2019, às 14:18, no fuso horário do Japão. E neste caso, o valor de `getTime()` será `1563513480000` (um valor completamente diferente, já que 19/07/2019, às 14:18 no Japão ocorreu em um instante diferente de 19/07/2019, às 14:18 no Brasil).

Claro que, dependendo do que você está fazendo com a data, pode não fazer diferença. Mas como você disse [nos comentários](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/398411/string-para-date-usando-javascript#comment782516_398421) que quer calcular a diferença para a data atual, pode ser que faça alguma diferença.

A string `"19/07/2019 14:18"`, por exemplo, foi gerada em qual fuso horário? Se for o mesmo que o browser está usando, tudo bem, pois você estará comparando datas e horas no mesmo timezone. Mas caso eles sejam diferentes (por exemplo, o browser está usando o fuso dos EUA, mas a string refere-se a um horário no Brasil - não foi dito onde nem como a string foi gerada, então não é seguro assumir que ela necessariamente usou o mesmo timezone do ambiente no qual o *parsing* ocorrerá), aí a comparação poderá retornar um resultado incorreto.

Se você usar o [código da resposta do Jorge](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/398421/112052), por exemplo, vai obter uma data correspondente a 19/07/2019, às 14:18 **em UTC** (que corresponde ao timestamp `1563545880000`, e às 11:18 no Horário de Brasília). Isso ocorre porque ele adicionou o `Z` no final, e [isso indica que a data/hora está em UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Coordinated_Universal_Time_(UTC)). Já a [solução do Luiz Felipe](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/398418/112052) não adiciona o `Z`, então a data/hora é interpretada usando-se o timezone do browser (comporta-se igual ao construtor que recebe os valores numéricos).

---

#### Mais um caso bizarro: horário de verão

[Atualmente o Brasil não tem horário de verão](http://www.planalto.gov.br/ccivil_03/_ato2019-2022/2019/decreto/D9772.htm), mas como isso é algo definido por governos, não há nenhuma garantia de que isso não mude no futuro (e [isso costuma mudar o tempo todo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/349822/112052)). De qualquer forma, existem duas situações envolvendo o horário de verão que podem causar alguns resultados estranhos ao se transformar uma string para data.

Um é quando o horário de verão começa. Por exemplo, no Brasil, em 4 de novembro de 2018, à meia-noite os relógios foram adiantados em uma hora. Em muitos sistemas isso já estava automatizado, e na prática o que acontece é que os relógios pulam automaticamente de 23:59:59.999 para 01:00. Isso quer dizer que todos os minutos entre meia-noite e 00:59 não existem neste dia, neste fuso-horário. Então o que acontece se tentarmos criar uma data exatamente neste dia e hora (o código abaixo assume que o timezone do seu sistema está configurado com o Horário de Brasília e ele está atualizado com as regras do horário de verão):

```js
let date = new Date(2018, 10, 4, 0, 30);
console.log(date, date.getTime());
```

O timestamp resultante é `1541302200000`, que corresponde a 04/11/2018, às 01:30 no Horário de Brasília (ou 03:30 em UTC). Como 00:30 não existe nesse dia (graças ao "pulo automático" do horário de verão), então o JavaScript automaticamente ajusta para 01:30 (é como se ele simulasse alguém olhando o relógio, percebendo que esqueceu de adiantá-lo e corrigindo o horário). Ou seja, se você receber a string `"04/11/2018 00:30"` e estiver usando o timezone do Brasil, pode ocorrer esta situação, caso a data e hora caiam neste intervalo de minutos que são pulados (também chamado de *DST Gap* - Daylight Saving Time Gap).

E quando o horário de verão termina, a situação é igualmente estranha. Em 2018, por exemplo, isso ocorreu em fevereiro. No dia 18/02/2018, à meia-noite, os relógios são atrasados de volta para 23:00 do dia 17. Isso quer dizer que todos os minutos entre 23:00 e 23:59 ocorrem **duas** vezes (uma no horário de verão, outra no horário "normal" - isso é chamado de *DST Overlap*). Então se você receber a string `"17/02/2018 23:30"`, qual das duas ocorrências será criada?

```js
let date = new Date(2018, 1, 17, 23, 30);
console.log(date, date.getTime());
```

O timestamp resultante foi `1518917400000`, que corresponde à primeira ocorrência das 23:30 (ainda em horário de verão). Se eu quiser a segunda ocorrência (depois que o horário de verão já terminou), tenho que somar uma hora manualmente:

```js
let date = new Date(2018, 1, 17, 23, 30);
date.setTime(date.getTime() + (1000 * 60 * 60));
console.log(date, date.getTime());
```

Isso pode fazer diferença se você for calcular a diferença com relação a data atual (no caso, pode dar uma hora de diferença). Infelizmente a API nativa do JavaScript não fornece uma maneira melhor de trabalhar com datas, e principalmente com fusos horários.

---

## Moment.js

Uma alternativa é usar o [Moment.js](https://momentjs.com/), uma API excelente para se trabalhar com datas. Exemplo:

```js
// transformar string em data
let data = moment("19/07/2019 14:18", "DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm");

// diferença em minutos para a data atual
let minutos = moment().diff(data, 'minutes');
console.log(minutos);

// se quiser um Date do JavaScript
let jsDate = data.toDate();
console.log(jsDate);
```

```html
<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.min.js"></script>
```

O Moment.js também usa o timezone do browser e tem o mesmo comportamento descrito acima durante os gaps e overlaps do horário de verão, então os mesmos pontos de atenção já citados se aplicam aqui.

Caso queira que as datas estejam em um fuso horário específico, pode usar o [Moment Timezone](https://momentjs.com/timezone/). Com ele você pode controlar qual o fuso horário usado para a data/hora:

```js
// data no horário de Brasília
let dataBr = moment.tz("04/11/2018 00:30", "DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm", "America/Sao_Paulo");
// data no fuso do Japão
let dataJp = moment.tz("04/11/2018 00:30", "DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm", "Asia/Tokyo");

// diferença em minutos para a data atual
console.log(moment().diff(dataBr, 'minutes'));
console.log(moment().diff(dataJp, 'minutes'));

// se quiser um Date do JavaScript
console.log(dataBr.toDate());
console.log(dataJp.toDate());
```

```html
<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment-timezone-with-data.min.js"></script>
```

Repare como a diferença em minutos e o `Date` correspondente é diferente, dependendo do timezone usado, já que 04/11/2018 00:30 ocorreu em instantes diferentes no Brasil e no Japão. Não sei se você vai precisar chegar a tal grau de preciosismo, mas de qualquer forma, "o diabo está nos detalhes", então fica aí a opção, caso seja necessário.

Os nomes dos timezones ("America/Sao_Paulo", "Asia/Tokyo") são definidos pelo [IANA Timezone Database](https://www.iana.org/time-zones). Para saber quais os timezones disponibilizados pelo Moment, use [`moment.tz.names()`](https://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/#/data-loading/getting-zone-names/).

Answer (score 1):

Converta a data para o Formato UTC
Veja  mais sobre em:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40768606/i-have-a-utc-string-and-i-want-to-convert-it-to-utc-date-object-in-javascript/40768745#40768745

```js
var string = "19/07/2019 14:18"
p = string.match(/(\d\d)\/(\d\d)\/(\d\d\d\d) (\d\d):(\d\d)/)
var date = new Date(p[3]+'-'+p[2]+'-'+p[1]+'T'+p[4]+':'+p[5]+':00Z');


console.log(date)
```

Comment: isso me retornou

 Fri Jul 19 2019 11:49:00 GMT-0300 (Horário Padrão de Brasília)

fazendo dessa forma conseguiria pegar a diferença dessa data com a data atual e me retornar a diferença em minutos usando o .getTime() ? @Jorge Costa

Comment: executando o exemplo na página o resultado é 2019-07-19T14:18:00.000Z"