# UnixTimeStamp para Date JavaScript

Tags: javascript, json, data, timestamp

Estou recebendo um JSON no qual a data está sendo retornada dessa forma:

```
    /Date(1563568740000+0200)/
```

Acredito que seja UnixTimeStamp, porém não consigo converter isso para o formato `Date` em JavaScript.

Já tentei fazer dessa forma:

```js
    console.log(new Date(Data*1000));
```

Porém no console do navegador me mostra "invalid date".

O que estou fazendo de errado?

Comment: Você pediu acesso ao JSON? Precisa recebe o dados e depois usar-lo. Esqueceu de adicionar tag json. Vários erros.

Comment: Como eu poderia fazer da forma correta ?@MauryDeveloper

Comment: OBS: eu estou tendo acesso ao json, porém só coloquei o trecho do código onde estou com dificuldades...

Comment: Por favor passe código completo. Pouca pessoa irão responde se tiver assim.

Comment: Isso pode te ajuda: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/847185/convert-a-unix-timestamp-to-time-in-javascript

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Se isso veio de um JSON, provavelmente é uma string contendo o texto `"/Date(1563568740000+0200)/"` (já que o [JSON](http://json.org/) não define um tipo específico para datas).

Uma maneira de resolver é extrair o conteúdo que interessa (no caso, o número gigante, que é um [timestamp](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/70473/112052)) e [usá-lo no construtor de `Date`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date#Unix_timestamp):

```js
let s = "/Date(1563568740000+0200)/";
let match = /\/Date\((\d+).*\)\//.exec(s);
let d = new Date(parseInt(match[1]));
console.log(d);
```

A regex usa `\d+` (um ou mais dígitos) entre parênteses, pois isso forma um [grupo de captura](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html), que posso recuperar depois com `match[1]` (eu uso 1 porque é o primeiro grupo de captura da regex).

Alguns caracteres (como a barra e os parênteses) devem ser escapados com `\`, pois eles possuem significado especial em regex, mas neste caso eu quero que eles sejam interpretados como os próprios caracteres, para que eles correspondam às barras e parênteses da string.

Depois uso [`parseInt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) para convertê-lo em número e passo para o construtor de `Date`.

Conforme já explicado [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/398485/112052), um `Date` encapsula apenas o valor do timestamp, então o restante (o offset +0200) é irrelevante para a sua criação. Por isso eu uso `.*` (zero ou mais caracteres), pois só serve para a regex ir até a próxima barra no final da string.

Comment: cara, me ajudou muito @hkotsubo

Comment: Você esqueceu de multiplicar por 1000. `let d = new Date(Math.trunc(+match[1]) * 1000);`

Comment: @MauryDeveloper Este valor já está em milissegundos e não precisa disso. Se eu multiplicar 1563568740000 por 1000, a data resultante estará no ano 51517

Comment: Desculpe então. Voto a favor a ti.