# Converter uma data do C# (Datetime), que foi transformado JSON, para Date do JavaScript

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, json, data

Quando realizo uma busca de dados no C#, ele me retorna o `DateTime` no formato `"/Date(123456789)/"`, mas não consigo converter para uma data válida no JavaScript.
Como um:

```
var data = new Date("/Date(123456789)/");
```

Ou:

```
var data = new "/Date(123456789)/".replace("/", "");
```

Comment: Se quer tratar isso no JavaScript, talvez isso ajude: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/398489/112052

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recomendo usar uma biblioteco chamada [moment](https://momentjs.com/), ela já se encarrega de fazer esta conversão para você sem precisar de muito esforço.

```js
var data = moment(dataDoResponse);
```

Comment: Valeu mesmo cara, de fato funcionou perfeitamente.

Answer (score 0):

Para resolver o problema, teremos de utilizar um regex.

O retorno do `$.Ajax()` ou `$.Post()` vai ser em uma variável como abaixo.

```
$.post("/Area/Controler/Ação", {parametros}, function (retorno) {
console.log(retorno) // "/Date(123456789)/"
        }, "Json");
```

Então podemos pegar a variável de retorno e converter para data conforme abaixo

```
$.post("/Area/Controler/Ação", {parametros}, function (retorno) {
 console.log(new Date(parseInt(retorno.replace(/[a-z A-z () /]/g, ""))));
  //Fri Jan 02 1970 07:17:36 GMT-0300 (Horário Padrão de Brasília)
 console.log(new Date(parseInt(retorno.replace(/[a-z A-z () /]/g, ""))).toLocaleString());
 //"02/01/1970 07:17:36"
                        }, "Json");
```

Comment: `A-z` ("A" maiúsculo e "z" minúsculo) é um intervalo que também considera os caracteres `^`, `_`, `[]` e outros, e os espaços dentro dos colchetes são desnecessários, já que o valor não tem espaços - [veja](https://regex101.com/r/LMdEj6/1). Então poderia ser apenas `[a-zA-Z()/]`, [veja](https://regex101.com/r/LMdEj6/2). Mas se quer remover tudo que não é número, poderia usar `\D`, [veja](https://regex101.com/r/LMdEj6/3). Mas se quiser validar o formato (só pega o número se estiver no formato "/Date(....)/"), aí pode usar o que sugeri em https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/398489/112052

Comment: Outro detalhe é verificar se o C# está gerando o valor em segundos ou milissegundos. O `Date` do JavaScript recebe o valor em milissegundos, mas o que vc usou nos testes parece estar em segundos (já que as datas geradas estão no ano 1970)

Comment: O C# envia os valores como milissegundos, o que fiz foi apenas passar um valor qualquer de exemplo. Não me importando com o fim da data, e sim, na conversão.

O seu também foi muito válido quanto ao regex, porém, o plugin "moment()" já ajuda muito por diminuir linhas de código.