# Como pegar apenas o horário de um Timestamp

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, timestamp

Usando o comando abaixo:

```
pd.to_datetime(1490195805, unit='s')
```

O retorno é:

```
Timestamp('2017-03-22 15:16:45')
```

Como faço para extrair apenas o horário: 15:16:45?

Comment: Olá, usa o `datetime`... `datetime.strftime(pd.to_datetime(1490195805, unit='s'), format="%H:%M:%S")`

Comment: Isto responde à sua pergunta? [Converter timestamp para data/hora](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/349793/converter-timestamp-para-data-hora)

Comment: Caso não precise obrigatoriamente usar o pandas, a pergunta sugerida acima já deve servir para o seu caso (é só adaptar o que tem lá - em especial [esta resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/349822/112052) - para mostrar apenas os campos de horário)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode fazer com a função time:

```
import pandas as pd

a = pd.to_datetime(1490195805, unit='s')
str(a.time())
```

Saída:

```
'15:16:45'
```