# Como converter a String "20190930120000[-3:BRT]" em LocalDateTime

Tags: java, data, datetime, java-8

Tenho a seguinte String: `"20190930120000[-3:BRT]"`.

Necessito converter em `LocalDateTime`.

Alguem sabe a mascara a ser utilizada no `DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("?????")`?

Cheguei até aqui:

```
LocalDateTime dataDoLancamento;
ZonedDateTime z = ZonedDateTime.parse("20190930120000[-3:BRT]",DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyyMMddHHmmss") );
dataDoLancamento =  z.toLocalDateTime();
```

Mas acabo obtendo esse erro:

> ```
>  java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '20190930120000[-3:BRT]' could not be parsed, unparsed text found at index 14
> ```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

O trecho `-3:BRT` eu acredito que seja o [*offset*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC_offset) (-3, a diferença em horas com relação a [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC)) e o timezone ([BRT](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/zones/brt) é a sigla comumente usada para "Brasília Time", que é o Horário Oficial de Brasília).

Dito isso, no Java 8 não é possível fazer o *parsing* de *offsets* **com apenas um dígito**, como é o caso do `-3`. Nesta versão do JDK, a [API só aceita com dois dígitos](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatterBuilder.html#appendOffset-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-), como `-03` por exemplo. [Isso só foi corrigido no Java 9](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50344734).

Sendo assim, o jeito é manipular a `String` manualmente.

---

Uma primeira alternativa é simplesmente ignorar o trecho "-3:BRT", já que você só está interessado na data e hora (e pelo que entendi, você não quer fazer conversões entre fusos horários, só quer pegar os valores de data e hora que estão na `String`, então bastaria ignorar este trecho mesmo):

```
String s = "20190930120000[-3:BRT]";
DateTimeFormatter parser = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuuMMddHHmmss");
LocalDateTime dt = LocalDateTime.parse(s.split("\\[")[0], parser);
```

---

Mas se quiser obter um [`ZonedDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html), considerando o *offset* e o timezone que estão na `String`, aí é um pouco mais complicado.

No Java 8, temos que adicionar o zero na frente do 3 para que o *offset* fique com 2 dígitos, pois aí é possível fazer o *parsing*:

```
String s = "20190930120000[-3:BRT]";
Set<ZoneId> preferredZones = new HashSet<ZoneId>();
preferredZones.add(ZoneId.of("America/Sao_Paulo"));
DateTimeFormatter parser = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
    // data, hora e "["
    .appendPattern("uuuuMMddHHmmss'['")
    // offset e os dois pontos
    .appendOffset("+HH", "+00").appendLiteral(':')
    // abreviação do timezone
    .appendZoneText(TextStyle.SHORT, preferredZones)
    // o "]"
    .appendLiteral(']')
    // criar o formatter
    .toFormatter();
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.parse(s.replaceFirst("(\\d+\\[[-+])(\\d:[A-Z]+\\])", "$10$2"), parser);
LocalDateTime dt = zdt.toLocalDateTime();
```

Para o *replace*, eu uso uma regex contendo dois [grupos de captura](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) (delimitados pelos parênteses). O primeiro grupo tem um ou mais números (`\\d+`), seguido do caractere `[` (que em regex deve ser escapado com `\`), seguido de um sinal de mais ou de menos (`[-+]`). O segundo grupo tem o número depois do sinal (apenas um dígito), seguido de dois pontos e uma ou mais letras, e por fim o caractere `]`.

No segundo argumento do *replace*, eu uso `$1` (tudo que foi capturado no grupo 1), um zero, e tudo que foi capturado no grupo 2 (`$2`). Ou seja, se o valor do *offset* tiver apenas um dígito, o zero é acrescentado. Se já tiver dois dígitos, nenhuma substituição é feita.

Um detalhe é que as abreviações de timezones (como "BRT") [são em muitos casos ambíguas, além de não serem nada padronizadas](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18407231) ("IST", por exemplo, é usada na [Índia](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/zones/ist), [Israel](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/zones/ist-israel) e [Irlanda](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/zones/ist-ireland), e há [muitos outros casos de ambiguidades](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_time_zone_abbreviations)).

Algumas API's até mapeiam abreviações para algum *default*, mas no caso do `DateTimeFormatter`, é necessário usar um `Set` de "timezones preferidos", que será usado para mapear a abreviação sem ambiguidade. No caso, usei `America/Sao_Paulo`, [que corresponde ao Horário de Brasília](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/259120/112052).

Outro detalhe é que o segundo parâmetro do [método `appendOffset`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatterBuilder.html#appendOffset-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-) é a `String` utilizada para quando o *offset* é zero. Eu usei `"+00"`, pois parece ser o "padrão" das strings que você está manipulando. Se não for, basta adaptar conforme seus casos de uso.

Por fim, se estiver usando Java >= 9, não é necessário fazer o *replace*, basta usar `"+H"` no [método `appendOffset`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatterBuilder.html#appendOffset-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-), ficando `appendOffset("+H", "+0")`.

---

Repare também que nos códigos acima eu usei `uuuu` em vez de `yyyy` para o ano. [Esta resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/177130/112052) explica o motivo (na seção "*Parse* e formatação com `String`").