# Capturar range de tempo em UNIX

Tags: python, data, timestamp

Estou tentando capturar em formato de data UNIX o range de tempo de 1 dia:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import time
import datetime
from datetime import datetime

now = datetime.now()

dateNow = '' + str(now.day - 1) + '/' + str(now.month) + '/' \
    + str(now.year) + ''

start = '' + dateNow + ' 00:00'
end = '' + dateNow + ' 23:59'

print(start)

startTimestamp = int(time.mktime(datetime.datetime.strptime(start,
                     '%d/%m/%Y %H:%M').timetuple()))

endTimestamp = int(time.mktime(datetime.datetime.strptime(end,
                   '%d/%m/%Y %H:%M').timetuple()))

print(startTimestamp)
```

Saída:

```
28/10/2019 00:00
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 17, in <module>    startTimestamp = int(time.mktime(datetime.datetime.strptime(start,AttributeError: type object 'datetime.datetime' has no attribute 'datetime'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Luis, você fez o `import` do `datetime` duas vezes, gerando inclusive o *warning* de redefinição.

Uma forma de corrigir, seria apenas remover o primeiro `import` do `datetime`, e corrigir também as linhas que utilizam do método `strptime`:

```
import time
from datetime import datetime

now = datetime.now()

dateNow = '' + str(now.day - 1) + '/' + str(now.month) + '/' \
    + str(now.year) + ''

start = '' + dateNow + ' 00:00'
end = '' + dateNow + ' 23:59'

print(start)

startTimestamp = int(time.mktime(datetime.strptime(start,
                     '%d/%m/%Y %H:%M').timetuple()))

endTimestamp = int(time.mktime(datetime.strptime(end,
                   '%d/%m/%Y %H:%M').timetuple()))

print(startTimestamp)
```

Comment: Entendi, achei que tinha que fazer outro import para usar nas variaveis start e end, muito obrigado !!

Comment: @LuisHenrique Vale lembrar que se o código rodar no dia 1 de qualquer mês, esse código já não funciona mais (pois ele tentará fazer o parsing do dia zero e dará erro): https://ideone.com/HaqTAE - [na minha resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/418778/112052) tem uma alternativa para esses casos :-)

Answer (score 1):

A [outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/418749/112052) já explicou os problemas do seu código, mas há um porém: se o código rodar no dia 1 de qualquer mês, você montará uma string correspondente ao dia zero, e [dará erro](https://ideone.com/HaqTAE).

Além disso, no seu código você criou um [`datetime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime-objects), transformou em strings, e depois transformou em `datetime` novamente, para depois retornar uma [`timetuple`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.timetuple) e por fim obter o timestamp. Mas não precisa dar essa volta toda.

Dá para fazer a mesma coisa só manipulando o `datetime` inicial. Basta usar [`date.today()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.today) para obter a data de hoje e subtrair um [`timedelta`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#timedelta-objects) para obter o dia anterior. Depois é só usar [`combine`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.combine) para combinar a data com um horário (usando [`time`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#time-objects) para definir o horário):

```
from datetime import datetime, date, time, timedelta

# dia de hoje menos 1 dia
d = date.today() - timedelta(days=1)

# combina o dia com o horário meia-noite
startTimestamp = datetime.combine(d, time(0, 0)).timestamp()
# combina o dia com o horário 23:59
endTimestamp = datetime.combine(d, time(23, 59)).timestamp()

print(startTimestamp) # 1572231600.0
print(endTimestamp) # 1572317940.0
```

Assim, eu consigo mudar o dia e horário conforme as regras indicadas. No segundo caso, eu setei a hora para 23, o minuto para 59 e o restante (segundos e fração de segundos) foram omitidos e serão zero, pois é isso que acontece quando você faz o *parsing* da string que você montou (que não tem os segundos e frações de segundo, então eles se tornam zero no *parsing*).

Note que neste caso os valores dos timestamps são mostrados com uma casa decimal (`1572231600.0`), já que eles são [`float`'s](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#float) (pois este é o retorno do [método `timestamp()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.timestamp)), já que ele também pode ter as frações de segundo (neste caso não tem porque em ambos os casos o valor é zero). Mas se quiser que sejam inteiros, pode usar `int` no resultado final: `int(datetime.combine....)`.

Este método é melhor não só por não "dar a volta" de converter para string e de volta para `datetime`, mas também porque ele não falha quando o dia é `1`. Ao subtrair um [`timedelta`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#timedelta-objects), já são feitos os ajustes necessários no mês e ano (por exemplo, se hoje fosse 1 de janeiro, ao subtrair 1 dia, precisaria ajustar o mês para dezembro e o ano para o anterior - **somente subtrair 1 do dia não funciona para todos os casos** - [veja](https://ideone.com/HaqTAE)).

Além disso, desta forma fica mais claro o que está acontecendo, e não precisa criar strings para depois converter de volta para `datetime`, basta usar os tipos existentes no módulo para manipular as datas diretamente.

---

## Cuidados com o timezone

Nos exemplos acima, o `startTimestamp` é `1572231600`. Mas lembre-se do que é o [timestamp](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/70473/112052): é um número que representa a quantidade de segundos desde o [*Unix Epoch*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time). Isso quer dizer que um mesmo valor de timestamp corresponde a uma data e hora diferentes, dependendo do fuso horário.

Por exemplo, o timestamp `1572231600` corresponde a:

- 28/10/2019 à meia-noite em São Paulo
- 28/10/2019 ao meio-dia em Tóquio
- **27**/10/2019 às 20:00 em Los Angeles

Todas as 3 datas e horários acima correspondem ao mesmo timestamp (ao mesmo instante, ao mesmo ponto na linha do tempo).

No caso, os `datetime`'s criados acima são "*naive*" (nome que o módulo dá para datas sem informação sobre o fuso horário). Só que para obter o timestamp, precisamos saber a qual fuso horário ele se refere (é dia 28 à meia-noite em qual lugar?). Como o `datetime` não possui tal informação, o Python usou a "hora local" (no meu caso, foi o Horário de Brasília). Por isso o timestamp retornado corresponde à meia-noite em São Paulo.

Mas [ao rodar esse mesmo código no IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/cWoPwM), por exemplo, o retorno foi `1572220800.0`, que corresponde à 28/10/2019 à meia-noite [**em UTC**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) (que por sua vez, corresponde à **27**/10/2019 às 21h em São Paulo). Isso porque o ambiente do IdeOne provavelmente está configurado com UTC (o mesmo acontece [se rodarmos no Repl.it](https://repl.it/repls/AustereDefinitiveStructure)).

Ou seja, este código pode dar um resultado diferente, dependendo do ambiente onde rodar. Se quiser controlar exatamente a qual timezone o `datetime` se refere, há algumas soluções.

Para Python <= 3.8 você pode usar o [módulo `pytz`](https://pypi.org/project/pytz/), que possui um bom suporte a timezones:

```
from datetime import datetime, date, time, timedelta
from pytz import timezone # precisa instalar: "pip install pytz"

d = date.today() - timedelta(days=1)
zone = timezone('America/Sao_Paulo')

startTimestamp = datetime.combine(d, time(0, 0)).astimezone(zone).timestamp()
endTimestamp = datetime.combine(d, time(23, 59)).astimezone(zone).timestamp()

print(startTimestamp) # 1572231600.0
print(endTimestamp) # 1572317940.0
```

Agora estou usando um timezone específico ("America/Sao_Paulo", que [corresponde ao Horário de Brasília](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/259124/112052)), e o resultado estará correto independente das configurações de onde o código estiver rodando.

Os nomes de timezones (como "America/Sao_Paulo", "Europe/London", etc) são padronizados pela [IANA](https://www.iana.org/time-zones), e você pode ver todos os disponíveis usando [`all_timezones`](https://pythonhosted.org/pytz/#helpers):

```
import pytz
print(pytz.all_timezones)
```

Mas se for usar o `pytz`, lembre-se de mantê-lo sempre atualizado, pois as informações de timezones mudam o tempo todo: só no Brasil, [tivemos uma mudança em 2018](https://g1.globo.com/economia/noticia/horario-de-verao-comecara-em-novembro-e-nao-mais-em-outubro-a-partir-de-2018-informa-planalto.ghtml) (o horário de verão começou em novembro em vez de outubro), e [em 2019 não teremos horário de verão](http://www.planalto.gov.br/ccivil_03/_Ato2019-2022/2019/Decreto/D9772.htm) (e isso é importante porque estar ou não em horário de verão muda a diferença com relação a UTC, e consequentemente muda o valor do timestamp obtido pelos códigos acima). E mesmo se for usar timezones de outros países, é igualmente importante, pois esse tipo de coisa [muda o tempo todo](https://www.timeanddate.com/news/time/).

Conforme a IANA lança novas atualizações (que você pode acompanhar se inscrevendo [nesta *mail-list*](https://mm.icann.org/pipermail/tz-announce/)), [o `pytz` é atualizado também](https://pypi.org/project/pytz/#latest-versions).

---

E a partir do Python 3.9 você pode usar o [módulo `zoneinfo`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zoneinfo.html). Seu uso é similar ao `pytz`:

```
from datetime import datetime, date, time, timedelta
from zoneinfo import ZoneInfo

d = date.today() - timedelta(days=1)
zone = ZoneInfo('America/Sao_Paulo')

startTimestamp = datetime.combine(d, time(0, 0)).astimezone(zone).timestamp()
endTimestamp = datetime.combine(d, time(23, 59)).astimezone(zone).timestamp()

print(startTimestamp) # 1572231600.0
print(endTimestamp) # 1572317940.0
```

E para consultar todos os timezones disponíveis, basta usar [`zoneinfo.available_timezones()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zoneinfo.html#zoneinfo.available_timezones):

```
import zoneinfo
print(zoneinfo.available_timezones())
```

Comment: Cara, simplesmente fantástica sua resposta, sua lógica de programação está muito boa, transformou o monstro que escrevi em poucas linhas, parabéns e obrigado por explicar detalhadamente !!

Comment: Só uma dúvida, caso eu quisesse transformar isso em range de tempo de 7 dias, como ficaria as variáveis ? teria que fazer ( start - 60 * 60 * 7) ?

Comment: @LuisHenrique Se quer subtrair 7 dias, faça `date.today() - timedelta(days = 7)`. O `timedelta` é justamente pra vc não ter que fazer essas contas

Comment: Mas ele irá capturar em um perído de 7 dias ou 7 dias atrás ?

Comment: Esse código acima subtrai, então o resultado é uma data 7 dias atrás.

Comment: entendi, no caso minha dúvida foi como ficaria para pegar em um perído de 7 dias, acho que me expressei mal, desculpe!

Comment: Se for o caso, é só fazer outra pergunta... Mas dependendo do que vc precisa, talvez já tenha no site, faça uma pesquisa antes :)

Comment: OK, mtt obrigado!!