# O que significam GMT e UTC?

Tags: terminologia, time, timestamp

Recentemente descobri o Unix Timestamp e acabei me deparando com as siglas GMT e UTC, gostaria de saber o que significam. Já dei uma pesquisada, mas não achei nada muito claro.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[Importante pergunta para entender melhor todo o conceito](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/70473/101).

GMT - [Greenwich Mean Time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greenwich_Mean_Time)

UTC - [Coordinated Universal Time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time)

O GMT é o horário considerado hora 0 e a partir dele vai diminuindo ou aumentando os fusos horários e ele passa por Londres (especificamente Royal Observatory em Greenwich) onde foi estabelecido que seria o horário básico da Terra. Existem alguns países ou regiões de países que o adotam pela sua posição geográfica. É dito que ele é baseado em observação astronômica porque o sol está no seu ponto mais alto está logo ali. É possível modificar a definição dele ou outros fusos (realisticamente não vai acontecer com o GMT, exceto por horário de verão).

Já o UTC é o horário neutro 0, e acontece o mesmo, mas sem a preocupação com a região que está, ele é universal. Nenhum país adota, é um conceito mais abstrato. É dito que ele é baseado em um relógio atômico. Ele é considerado o termo mais correto para declarar neutralidade de tempo, apenas porque hoje em dia nos preocupamos (alguns de nós na Terra) com a conceituação correta das coisas. Ele é estável. Não está sujeito a ajustes legais como horário de verão.

Partindo do UTC 0000 vai se chegando aos outros fusos horários de acordo com os meridianos da Terra. Então o Brasil tem regiões com mais de um UTC e ele pode mudar por causa do horário de verão. O horário de Brasília costuma ser UTC-0300, mas em horário de verão ele é UTC-0200. Enquanto que o horário regionalizado pode ser o BRT (UTC-0300) ou o BRST (UTC-0200). No passado usa-se o GMT para calcular a diferença das outras regiões, mas isso é um absurdo porque o GMT pode ser móvel, pelo menos por causa de horário de verão.

Para todos os efeitos se você não está **descrevendo** o horário local de alguma forma o UTC neutro deveria ser usado, ele é um horário estável e pode ser apresentando corretamente de acordo com o contexto que você quiser, o horário é sempre o mesmo e não deveria mudar. Se o horário não for UTC neutro só deveria ser usado indicando qual o fuso que está usado, caso contrário você tem uma informação parcial. Se não tiver isso você pode ter dois fatos ocorrendo com uma hora de diferença (ou outras diferenças mais raras) no mesmo local com o mesmo horário descritivo (por causa do horário de verão).

Eu falo muito que o horário é só um ponto na linha do tempo e só existe uma linha do tempo, você não pode ter lidar com horário que seja ambíguo onde o ponto está, o UTC é essa linha universal. O tempo não está sujeito ao local da Terra que você está.

Aos contrário do que as pessoas pensam eles não são sinônimos, embora em geral acabe sendo a mesma coisa. Mas há diferenças sutis, como o tal do [*leap second*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leap_second) já que o sol nunca está errado, o relógio atômico tem um erro mínimo. Para a maioria dos efeitos em programação, incluindo *timestamp* o UTC é preferido, só deve ser usado a forma regionalizada se o conceito for adequado para seu uso.

Artigos úteis sobre o assunto:

- [Falsehoods programmers believe about time](https://infiniteundo.com/post/25326999628/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-time), e [parte 2](https://infiniteundo.com/post/25509354022/more-falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-time)
- [Falsehoods About Time and Time Zones](https://www.creativedeletion.com/2015/01/28/falsehoods-programmers-date-time-zones.html)
- [Críticas ao artigo sobre falsidades sobre o tempo](https://gist.github.com/thanatos/eee17100476a336a711e)
- [Falsehoods programmers believe about Unix time](https://alexwlchan.net/2019/05/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-unix-time/)

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Inclusive a NASA com parceria da SpaceX colocou em órbita (25/06/2019) um relógio desse que foi citados `Deep Space Atomic Clock`

Comment: Eu adoro esses artigos de *falsehoods* :-)

Comment: https://github.com/kdeldycke/awesome-falsehood

Answer (score 20):

Antigamente, não havia uma preocupação tão grande com relação ao horário de outros lugares, e cada cidade adotava seu próprio horário local, muitas vezes com diferença de alguns minutos entre localidades próximas.

Com o aumento das linhas ferroviárias, principalmente nos EUA e Reino Unido, isso se tornou um problema. Como cada cidade tinha seu próprio fuso horário local, as tabelas de horários de saída e chegada dos trens acabavam ficando enormes. Só nos EUA, por exemplo, uma das companhias mantinha uma tabela com horários de mais de 100 cidades, porém, estima-se que existiam mais de 300 fusos diferentes no país.

Como a manutenção destas tabelas de horários tornou-se impraticável, resolveram padronizar os fusos horários da forma que conhecemos hoje. Em vez de cada cidade ter sua própria hora local, uma região inteira – que poderia ser inclusive um país inteiro – passava a seguir o mesmo horário.

### E assim surgiu o GMT

Por volta de 1847, a maioria das companhias ferroviárias inglesas já usavam o "Horário de Londres" (*London Time*), que era definido pelo Observatório Real de Greenwich. Porém, somente em 1880 isso passou a ser adotado pelo restante do país. Com isso, a ilha da Grã Bretanha adotou o *Greenwich Mean Time* – também conhecido pela sigla **GMT** – em 2 de agosto de 1880.

Quatro anos depois, em outubro de 1884, ocorreu a *International Meridian Conference*, em Washington D.C., EUA. Nesta conferência, decidiu-se pelo uso do Meridiano de Greenwich como a base a partir da qual todos os fusos horários seriam definidos. Um dos principais fatores que influenciaram a decisão é que o Observatório de Greenwich produzia os dados mais confiáveis da época.

A partir daí, cada país passou a adotar um ou mais fusos horários baseados em Greenwich, com diferença de um determinado número de horas para mais ou para menos ([nem sempre são horas inteiras](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/time-zones-interesting.html)). O horário oficial de Brasília, por exemplo, passou a ser de 3 horas antes de Greenwich.

Teoricamente, os fusos horários deveriam seguir os meridianos, com variação de uma hora a cada 15 graus de longitude, mas na prática os países acabam usando as suas divisas ou qualquer outro critério, resultando em várias regiões do mundo que, mesmo estando na mesma longitude, possuem fusos diferentes.

### UTC, o novo GMT

Na mesma conferência que definiu o GMT como o padrão a ser adotado – a *International Meridian Conference*, em 1884 – também foi definido o *Universal Time* (**UT**), que é basicamente definido pela velocidade média de rotação da terra. Há várias versões do UT (como o UT0, UT1 e UT2), cada uma com um modo específico de ser calculado, sempre levando em conta observações e cálculos astronômicos. A versão UT1, combinada com o *International Atomic Time* (TAI) – que é medido por relógios atômicos de alta precisão – resulta no padrão **UTC** (*Coordinated Universal Time*, ou "Tempo Universal Coordenado").

Na época, ingleses e franceses discutiam se a sigla deveria ser CUT (pois em inglês o nome é *Coordinated Universal Time*) ou TUC (em francês, *Temps Universel Coordonné*). No fim, decidiu-se por uma sigla que não favorecesse nenhum dos idiomas, e assim surgiu o nome **UTC**.

Não vou entrar nos detalhes específicos de como o UTC é calculado (caso tenha ficado curioso, veja a [descrição da Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Time/). O que importa aqui é o fato de que em 1972 ele passou a ser o padrão adotado para fusos horários.

Ou seja, a partir de 1972, o UTC substituiu o GMT, portanto todos os horários locais do mundo são definidos como uma diferença em relação a UTC. O horário oficial de Brasília, por exemplo, está 3 horas atrás de UTC. Para descrever tal informação, costuma-se escrever como `UTC-03:00`, `-03:00`, `-0300` ou simplesmente `-03`. **Esta diferença é chamada de *UTC offset*, ou simplesmente *offset*.** Pode-se então dizer que o horário oficial de Brasília tem um offset negativo (-3 horas, ou 3 horas atrás de UTC).

> Não há uma tradução certa para *UTC offset* em português. As opções oferecidas pelo dicionário (deslocamento, compensação) ou mesmo palavras com sentido próximo (como "diferença") na minha opinião não são satisfatórias. Por isso, usarei o termo em inglês.
>
> Os formatos `-03:00`, `-0300` e `-03` são definidos pela [norma ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601), que define formatos para representar datas e horas.

Depois que foi substituído pelo UTC, o GMT passou a ser apenas o nome do fuso horário adotado pelo Reino Unido – e mais alguns países – quando não está em horário de verão (portanto, [eles não são a mesma coisa](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/gmt-utc-time.html)). Você pode ver todos os países que adotam GMT [nesta lista](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/zones/gmt). Na verdade, estes países estão em `UTC+00:00` (o offset é zero, ou seja, nenhuma diferença com relação a UTC).

É mais comum ver o offset zero sendo escrito como `Z`, e também é chamado de *Zulu Time*, já que a mesma letra é usada para definir a *Zulu Time Zone*, que é um dos [*timezones* militares](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_military_time_zones/). Ou seja, uma data e hora escrita como `2019-02-10T10:00Z` (com o "Z" no final), indica que aquela data e hora referem-se a UTC.

Apesar disso, você ainda verá em muitos lugares um offset escrito como `GMT-03:00` ou `GMT-3`, ou alguma outra variação. Conceitualmente não está correto, já que o padrão atual é o UTC, mas algumas APIs ainda aceitam estes formatos, provavelmente por questões de retrocompatibilidade.

Outro detalhe importante é que cada país adotou o GMT e/ou UTC em uma data diferente, então deve-se tomar certo cuidado ao verificar datas antigas, especialmente antes da definição de cada um destes padrões. Para datas anteriores à padronização ou adoção dos fusos atuais, é usado o *Local Mean Time* (LMT), que é baseado na longitude do local em questão. Com isso, o resultado são offsets "quebrados", como `UTC -3:06:28` (3 horas, 6 minutos e 28 segundos atrás de UTC).

Você pode ver mais informações sobre GMT x UTC nestes artigos:

- [Diferenças entre eles](https://codeofmatt.com/2014/06/18/utc-vs-gmt/), sob uma ótica mais prática do que científica.
- [A few things you should know about Unix timestamps](https://codeofmatt.com/please-dont-call-it-epoch-time/#a-few-things-you-should-know-about-unix-timestamps-).

---

<sup>*Trecho adaptado [deste livro](https://www.casadocodigo.com.br/products/livro-datas-e-horas?_pos=2&_sid=91c0a2fbf&_ss=r).*</sup>