# Como tornar apresentavel uma String que esta nesse formato yyyy-mm-dd HH:mm:ss.fff

Tags: java, data

Tenho uma data que é um retorno do banco de dados que vem nesse formato `yyyy-mm-dd HH:mm:ss.fff`, como eu posso transformar isso em `dd-mm-yyyy HH:mm`

Exemplo: 
A minha data está assim: `2015-01-16 07:49:45.0` e eu quero deixar ela dessa forma: `16-01-2015 07:49`

Comment: Isso resolve seu problema: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/25197/converter-data-dd-mm-aaaa-para-yyy-mm-ddthhmmss. Lembrando que deve ser usado "M" (maiúscula) para mês.

Comment: Estou tentando usar o `String formatedDate = DateFormat.format("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss", receivedDate).toString();` porem da erro no `.format`

Comment: Que erro o ´.format´ apresenta ?

Comment: `the method format(date) in the type date format is not applicable for the arguments (String, Date)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Se você for tratar só depois que recebeu do banco precisa fazer isso aqui:

```
DateFormat dfBanco = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
DateFormat dfJava = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm");
String dataFormatada = dfJava.format(dfBanco.parse("2015-01-16 07:49:45.0"));
```

Saída:

```
16-01-2015 07:49
```

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente, muito obrigado.

Answer (score 1):

No código abaixo, estou usando um [SimpleDataFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

Essa classe será a responsável por armazenar o formato e receber os objetos de String para criar a data no formato desejado

```
public class MainTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
        java.util.Date suaData = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm")
                .parse("2015-01-16 07:49:45.0");//colocar origem da data
        System.out.println(suaData );
    }
}
```